# How long is my number?

Tags: code-golf, number, integer

### Challenge

Given an integer \$Q\$ in the range \$-2^{100} ≤ Q ≤ 2^{100}\$, output the number of digits in that number (in base 10).

### Rules

Yes, you may take the number as a string and find its length.

All mathematical functions are allowed.

You may take input in any base, but the output must be the length of the number in base 10.

Do not count the minus sign for negative numbers. The number will never have a decimal point.

Zero can either have one or zero digits.

Assume the input will always be a valid integer.

### Examples

```
Input > Output

-45 > 2
12548026 > 8
33107638153846291829 > 20
-20000 > 5
0 > 1 or 0
```

### Winning

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 1 byte

```
l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@5/z/3@8oZGxien/KAA)

Another builtin solution, but this one has the shortest name (unless someone finds a language which does this task in zero bytes). This should work in both Brachylog 1 and Brachylog 2.

This is a function submission (the TIO link contains a command-line argument that causes the interpreter to run an individual function rather than a whole program), partly because otherwise we'd have to spend bytes on output, partly because Brachylog's syntax for negative numbers is somewhat unusual and making this program a function resolves any potential arguments about input syntax.

It's often bothered me that most of Brachylog's builtins treat negative numbers like positive ones, but that fact ended up coming in handy here. I guess there are tradeoffs involved with every golfing language.

Comment: This is where I stop scrolling... this is outrageous!

Answer (score 44):

## [Taxi](https://bigzaphod.github.io/Taxi/), 1118 bytes

```
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Post Office:w 1 l 1 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.Go to Chop Suey:n 1 r 1 l 4 r 1 l.Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.'-' is waiting at Writer's Depot.Go to Writer's Depot:n 1 l 3 l.Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.Go to Crime Lab:n 1 r 2 r 2 l.Switch to plan "n" if no one is waiting.-1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.[n]0 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.Go to Starchild Numerology:s 1 r 1 l 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Cyclone:e 1 l 2 r.[r]Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Zoom Zoom:n.Go to Addition Alley:w 1 l 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.Go to Chop Suey:n 1 r 2 r.Switch to plan "f" if no one is waiting.Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.Go to Sunny Skies Park:n 1 l 3 l 1 l.Go to Cyclone:n 1 l.Switch to plan "r".[f]Go to Addition Alley:n 1 l 2 l.Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.Go to The Babelfishery:n 1 r 1 r.Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.Go to Post Office:n 1 l 1 r.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/taxi#tVTBasMwDP2VRy891azdTrl1G@wytkIGg5Ue3ERJTF052A6lX98lWZK2WdeFwQ5KsCzrPenJPkyhHHZSecUppEfopY0ypWO8FFuyRpt0L54MvMHCOI/XJFERBTtMoUuz1V8sVLQpckjk0jnilCxSUyUsTz1kJkdYUJulWwfcnsfdkDxWbQnPci3Gk3GP9LtVnuzY4ZFy4xugc2eNpnE7GKVh264btrPatAh3ykdZFZFryRjxCCoBGximE3JiMqi/S17dDNfh0lbgumZWNvutzH2kS6ZXY@ZxXLIxjLnWR/W@DgbUwFixtKt/QfowZlt/Am4852HHEfxDFb0ZrOroK5r8oOg1sLBg3iPcKHJYSLtpBeu5j7NYT/15Z@u9b2zsSCyT1cU@8CDF3zLCvVyTTpTLyLad6Lu7S3m9qydPwYXHgTtlDodP)

Ungolfed:

```
1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Post Office: west 1st left 1st right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Chop Suey.
Go to Chop Suey: north 1st right 1st left 4th right 1st left.
Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.
'-' is waiting at Writer's Depot.
Go to Writer's Depot: north 1st left 3rd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Crime Lab.
Go to Crime Lab: north 1st right 2nd right 2nd left.
Switch to plan "n" if no one is waiting.
-1 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
[n]
0 is waiting at Starchild Numerology.
Go to Starchild Numerology: south 1st right 1st left 1st left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Cyclone: east 1st left 2nd right.
[r]
Pickup a passenger going to Cyclone.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Zoom Zoom: north.
Go to Addition Alley: west 1st left 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Addition Alley.
Go to Chop Suey: north 1st right 2nd right.
Switch to plan "f" if no one is waiting.
Pickup a passenger going to Sunny Skies Park.
Go to Sunny Skies Park: north 1st left 3rd left 1st left.
Go to Cyclone: north 1st left.
Switch to plan "r".
[f]
Go to Addition Alley: north 1st left 2nd left.
Pickup a passenger going to The Babelfishery.
Go to The Babelfishery: north 1st right 1st right.
Pickup a passenger going to Post Office.
Go to Post Office: north 1st left 1st right.
```

Explanation:

```
Pickup the input and split it into individual characters
Pickup the value 1.
If the first character a hyphen, add -1. Otherwise, add 0.
Keep picking up characters and adding 1 until you're out.
Convert the running total to a string and print to stdout.
```

Comment: I've been a lurker in this exchange for a long time, but have never seen something like this

Comment: @CupofJava https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/57064/65836

Comment: Will this run out of gas if the number is long enough?

Comment: This is a bigger brainfuck than brainfuck.

Comment: @RobertFraser That's why we stop at `Zoom Zoom` in every loop of `plan "r"`. I just tested it up to 100,000 digits and it never ran out of gas. I didn't calculate it but I suppose it takes in more than enough fare to pay for the gas it's using so it fills up the tank on every loop.

Comment: @CupofJava Welcome to esoteric languages. [Chicken](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Chicken), [Cow](https://bigzaphod.github.io/COW/), and [Unary](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unary) are some that I find the most hilarious. I presumed that would be more [Taxi on PCG](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=Taxi%20is%3aanswer) but it looks like just me and Erik the Outgolfer.

Comment: @CupofJava OH MY GOSH how did I forget about [Shakespeare](http://shakespearelang.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 21):

### Mathematica, 13 bytes

```
IntegerLength
```

There's a built-in... returns `0` for `0`.

Comment: Mathematica prevails :D

Comment: not in code *golf* it doesn't :)

Comment: `There's a built-in`: When isn't there?

Answer (score 16):

## dc, 3

```
?Zp
```

Note that normally `dc` requires negative numbers to be given with `_` instead of the more usual `-`.  However, in this case, either may be used.  If `-` is given, then `dc` treats this as a subtraction on an empty stack, throws `dc: stack empty`, and then continues with the rest of the number; Thus the result is no different.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#RYxNCoMwFAb3nuJDWlwFkpefRoT2Ht2V5IluEjFZ9u6pCNJZzsDMeUflUsOnMNYEYSwUWeMlOWit5MNpr6z2xtGoPI0QJA8gJ8Tc4WDb11Rn9PcC8USP2/U7K4cl/xW@iAGCMbTXe2tDF3Pi9gM).

```
?    # input
 Z   # measure length
  p  # print
```

Comment: Couldn't this just be `Z` as a function submission? `dc`'s a concatenative language with quote+dup+eval operators, it can therefore reuse arbitrary strings of code.

Answer (score 14):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 2 bytes

```
\d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#U9VwT/gfk/L/v66JKZehkamJhYGRGZexsaGBuZmxhaGpsYWJmZGloYWRJZeukQEQAAA)

Retina doesn't really know what numbers are, so the input is treated as a string and we simply count the digit characters.

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
Äg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@4Jf3/f10TUwA) or [Try All Tests!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#qymr/H@4Jf1/pdLh/VYKSvY6/3VNTLkMjUxNLAyMzLiMjQ0NzM2MLQxNjS1MzIwsDS2MLLl0jQyAgMsAAA)

```
Ä  # Absolute value
 g # Length
```

Comment: `Ä`, huh? Not `þ`? Fair enough.

Comment: @carusocomputing I thought of `Ä` first, but `þ` would handle a decimal point, so it's a little better I guess.

Comment: Just cool how 2 people came up with 2 different 2 byte solutions within 2 minutes of each other, I don't think there's a third though; trying to think of one.

Answer (score 6):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 16 bytes

```
//; 'q<)e
o!@i -
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@vb62gXmijmcqVr@iQqaD7/7@uiSkA)

#### Explanation

Finding a half-decent layout for this was quite tricky. I'm still not super happy with it because of the spaces, the `<` and the `;`, but this is the best I could do for now.

String length is one of those very common built-ins that doesn't exist in Alice, because its input is a string and its output is an integer (and all Alice commands are strictly integers to integer or strings to strings). We can measure a string's length by writing it to the tape in Ordinal mode and then finding its end in Cardinal mode.

```
/      Reflect to SE. Switch to Ordinal. While in Ordinal mode, the IP will bounce
       diagonally up and down through the code.
!      Store an implicit empty string on the tape, does nothing.
;      Discard an implicit empty string, does nothing.
i      Read all input as a string.
'-     Push "-".
<      Set the horizontal component of the IP's direction to west, so we're bouncing
       back now.
-      Remove substring. This deletes the minus sign if it exists.
'i     Push "i".
;      Discard it again.
!      Store the input, minus a potential minus sign, on the tape.
/      Reflect to W. Switch to Cardinal. The IP immediately wraps to the
       last column.
e)     Search the tape to the right for a -1, which will be found at the end
       of the string we stored there.
<      Does nothing.
q      Push the tape head's position, which is equal to the string length.
'<sp>  Push " ".
;      Discard it again.
/      Reflect to NW. Switch to Ordinal. The IP immediately bounces off
       the top boundary to move SW instead.
o      Implicitly convert the string length to a string and print it.
       IP bounces off the bottom left corner, moves back NE.
/      Reflect to S. Switch to Cardinal.
!      Store an implicit 0 on the tape, irrelevant.
       The IP wraps back to the first line.
/      Reflect to NE. Switch to Ordinal. The IP immediately bounces off
       the top boundary to move SE instead.
@      Terminate the program.
```

I also tried taking care of the minus sign in Cardinal mode with `H` (absolute value), but the additional mode switch always ended up being more expensive in my attempts.

Answer (score 6):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 37 bytes

```
-[+>+[+<]>+]>->,[-<->]<[>+>],[<+>,]<.
```

Output is by byte value.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#bY@9DsIwDIT3PIV3N5lgs@4p2CIPBYJaqT@oLeLxi1NKoRKeYt19d87sI4Mji4IVHkX04qESwdAiCqNQCfOpqke69f2UBrJXlYZEU0/3oe4mmqpE3aM9Z62ja7rUbdlQOdIzNY1zItErbxMAB3z3LFuZz41QRLYLrHvZZBkFLAE7yJhfwu0RfQNxJXLiOmYIYmbODvvmEiT68W0VzjLCYpG/GSblw3OtzP5wfAE)

#### Explanation

```
-[+>+[+<]>+]>->  Constant for 45 (from esolangs wiki)
,                Read a byte of input
[-<->]           Subtract that byte from 45
<[>+>]           If the result is nonzero then increment a cell and move to the right
                 (0 means it was a minus; so not counted)
,[<+>,]          Read a byte and increment the cell to its left until EOF is reached
<.               Print the cell that was being incremented
```

Comment: Is it possible to add a footer to the TIO link which outputs the result as a number?

Comment: @BetaDecay Added

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks :D

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, 23 Bytes

```php
<?=-~log10(abs($argn));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVTJQsuayt/tvY2@rW5eTn25ooJGYVKwBltTUtP7/HwA)

log of base 10 of the absolute value plus one cast to int

for zero as input log10 gives back `INF` which is interpreted as false

The better way is to replace `$argn` with `$argn?:1` +3 Bytes

## PHP, 27 Bytes

```php
<?=strlen($argn)-($argn<0);
```

string length minus boolean is lower then zero

+2 Bytes for string comparision `$argn<"0"`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVdI1NTE2MjQwNDI0MjYxMTVTsuayt/tvY29bXFKUk5qnAVamqQuhbQw0rf//BwA)

### PHP, 32 Bytes

```php
<?=preg_match_all("#\d#",$argn);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVTJQsuayt/tvY29bUJSaHp@bWJKcEZ@Yk6OhpByToqykA1amaf3/PwA)

Regex count all digits

### 35 Bytes

```php
<?=strlen($argn)-strspn($argn,"-");
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVTJQsuayt/tvY29bXFKUk5qnARbX1AXyigugPB0lXSVN6///AQ)

string length minus count `-`

[strspn](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strspn.php)

Comment: The first one doesn't work, for example, for `10`, because `^` has lower priority. You can fix it with `-~`.

Comment: Why not simply `<?=strlen(abs($argn));` ?

Comment: @user63956 The version with log10 can't work in cases of input zero so I delete it.

Comment: @roberto06 if i use abs for higher numbers the string will be interpreted as `1.0E+64` for example gives back 7 and not 64

Comment: @JörgHülsermann Why not just `$argn?:1`? It would be 26 bytes with `log10()` and `abs()`.

Comment: @user63956 I was a little confused through your first post. I am not sure if you forget to add 1 or cast to int. I count 28 Bytes

Comment: @JörgHülsermann `-~$x` is equivalent to `((int)$x)+1`. `<?=-~log10(abs($argn?:1));` seems to work.

Comment: @user63956 Yes it works now I have understand what you mean. Thank You And we can remove the ternary operator cause `log10(0)` is interpreted as false

Answer (score 5):

## Fortran 95 (gfortran), <s>121</s> <s>96</s> 95 bytes

```
program c
character b
call get_command_argument(1,b,length=i)
print*,i-index(b,'-')
end program
```

Explanation:
Subtracts the index of the '-' sign from the length of the argument.
Arrays start at 1 in Fortran, and index() returns 0 if symbol not found.

*Edit: Switched to implicit integer "i", also consolidated argument getter.*

*Edit: -1 byte thanks to @Tsathoggua*

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 5):

## [GNU AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), <strike>18</strike> <strike>17</strike> 15 bytes

```
$1=gsub(/\w/,1)
```

Substitutes every <strike>number</strike> <strike>character (except for the minus sign)</strike> alphanumeric character of the input for another character (here, the number 1), and assigns the number of substitutions to the output.

Thanks for cnamejj and manatwork for helping me saving some bytes!

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxdA2vbg0SUM/plxfx1Dz/39dE1MuQyNTEwsDIzMuY2NDA3MzYwtDU2MLEzMjS0MLI0suXSMDIOAyAAA)

## [AWK](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html), 17 bytes

```
$1=gsub(/[^-]/,1)
```

This is a previous answer, that should work on any Awk version, not only GNU's.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxdA2vbg0SUM/Ok43Vl/HUPP/f10TUy5DI1MTCwMjMy5jY0MDczNjC0NTYwsTMyNLQwsjSy5dIwMg4DIAAA)

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, nice first answer!

Comment: You could use `gsub(".",1)` to knock off a few more characters too.  Nice idea for how to do this BTW.

Comment: Thanks, guys! @cnamejj I could not make this work with negative numbers.

Comment: You're right...  I mis-read the problem description, sorry about that!

Comment: @cnamejj you have just gave me an idea to regex every character, but the minus sign. I'll save one byte.

Comment: Although there is no `\d` in AWK, we still have `\w` (at least in `gawk`, but not in `mawk`), which is good enough in this case.

Comment: @manatwork wow! I missed that by a mile! Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

## PowerShell, 24 Bytes

```
"$args"-replace'-'|% Le*
```

casts the "absolute" value of the input args to a string and gets the 'length' property of it.

1 byte shorter than `"".Length`

until someone finds a better way to get the abs of a number in PS this is probably as short as it will get.

Comment: How about `"$args".trim('-')|% Le*` ? :)

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 2 bytes

```
þg
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394X/r//7qGRsZ6JqZmAA)

```
   # Implicit input [a]...
þ  # Only the digits in [a]...
 g # length of [a]...
   # Implicit output.
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>15</s> 11+1 = <s>16</s> 12 bytes

Uses the `-n` flag.

```
p~/$/-~/\d/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#U1YsKk2qVNDN@19Qp6@ir1unH5Oi//@/rokpl6GRqYmFgZEZl7GxoYG5mbGFoamxhYmZkaWhhZEll66RARBwGQAA)

#### Explanation

```
                  # -n flag gets one line of input implicitly
p                 # Print
 ~/$/             # Position of end of line (aka string length) in input
     -            # minus
      ~/\d/       # Position of first digit (1 if negative number, 0 otherwise)
```

Comment: What magic is this?

Comment: @Chowlett added an explanation.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>31</s> 22 bytes

*-9 bytes thanks to Rod.*

```python
lambda i:len(`abs(i)`)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQaZWTmqeRkJhUrJGpmaD5v6AoM69EIU1D18RUkwvGMTQyNbEwMDJDiBgbGxqYmxlbGJoaW5iYGVkaWhhZImR1jQyAAME30PwPAA)

Comment: `len(\`abs(s)\`)` with number as input is shorter

Comment: Too bad Python doesn't have function composition. It would be just `len∘repr∘abs`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
DL
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@/i8///f10TUwA)**

This does literally what was asked:

```
DL - Main link number n         e.g. -45
D  - convert to a decimal list       [-4,-5]
 L - get the length                  2
```

Comment: That's an interesting built-in there, does `D` work on decimals? Would `-1.2` output `[-1,-0.2]`? Tried it myself, it does not.

Comment: Not quite, the base conversion only goes down to the units so, for example, `654.321D` would yield `[6,5,4.321]` (well actually `[6.0,5.0,4.321000000000026]`)

Comment: `[-6.0, -5.0, -4.321000000000026]`, actually, apparently.

Comment: Ah - yeah just edited - floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), 5 bytes

```
q'--,
```

String based.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@1@orqur8/@/AQA)

9 bytes for a purely math-based solution:

```
riz)AmLm]
```

Or another 5 with base conversion:

```
riAb,
```

Comment: Or also 5: `rizs,`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>27</s> <s>26</s> <s>25</s> 24 bytes

Takes input as a string.

```
s=>s.match(/\d/g).length
```

- Saved two bytes thanks to Arnauld.

Comment: Your title says 23 bytes, but your code is 24... However, this is 23 bytes: ``s=>`${s>0?s:-s}`.length``!

Comment: Thanks, @DomHastings. You should post yours as a separate answer as it's a different approach to mine.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 63 bytes

```
([({})]((((()()()()())){}{})){}{})((){[()](<{}>)}{})([{}][]<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@68RrVFdqxmrAQKaMKipWV0LFIWQQPHqaA2gEpvqWjtNsEh0dW1sdKyNneb//7qGBv91EwE)

This is 62 bytes of code and +1 byte for the `-a` flag.

I tried two other approaches, but unfortunately both of them were longer:

```
([]<({}[((((()()()()())){}{})){}{}]<>)((){[()](<{}>)}{})>)({}[{}])

([]<>)<>({}<>)((((([][]())){}{})){}{}[{}])((){[()](<{}>)}{})([{}]{})
```

This *should* be a very short answer. In fact, if we didn't have to support negative numbers, we could just do:

```
([]<>)
```

But we have to compare the first input with 45 (ASCII `-`) first, which is most of the byte count of this answer.

An arithmetic solution might be shorter.

Comment: I count 62 bytes..?

Comment: @totallyhuman see my edit.

Comment: 49 bytes: `([{}]((((()()()()())){}{})){}{})({(<()>)}{}[]<>)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 bytes

```
a s l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/japt#@5@oUKyQ8/@/rpGpOQA)

## Explanation

```
 a s l
Ua s l
Ua     # take the absolute value of the input
   s   # and turn it into a string
     l # and return its length
```

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 20 bytes

```
->a{a.abs.to_s.size}
```

Comment: FYI: in order to call it you do: `->a{a.abs.to_s.size}[-95]`

Comment: or just classic way - `->a{a.abs.to_s.size}.call(-92)`

Comment: not a golfy way :D

Answer (score 2):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 2 bytes

```
âL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/rprogn-2#@394kc////91DS1MTMzMTUwMzI3NDSxNTQ3NDE0B)

Simply gets the absolute value of the input, and counts the digits.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 4 bytes

```
l`.a
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%60.a&debug=0)

[All test cases](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=l%60.a&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=-45%0A12548026%0A33107638153846291829%0A20000%0A0&debug=0)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 9 + 1 = 10 bytes

```perl
$_=y/-//c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#@68Sb1upr6uvn/z/v66JKZehkamJhYGRGZexsaGBuZmxhaGpsYWJmZGloYWRJZeukQEQcBn8yy8oyczPK/6vm1MAAA)

Run with `-p` (1 byte penalty).

### Explanation

```perl
$_=y/-//c
            {implicit from -p: for each line of input}
   y/ //    In {the input}, replace
        c     everything except
     -        '-'
$_=         Store number of replacements back in $_
            {implicit from -p: output $_}
```

We treat the input as a string in order to handle numbers outside the 64-bit range. One interesting trick here is that we don't have to specify what we're replacing the nonhyphens *with*; we can still count the number of replacements that occur.

The TIO link uses `-l` in order to let us run the program on multiple data without the newlines between them interfering. If the program only has to run once, we can do without it, so long as there's no final newline on the input.

Answer (score 2):

### R, 18 bytes

```
nchar(abs(scan()))
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 23 bytes

```js
s=>`${s>0?s:-s}`.length
```

Different approach to [Shaggy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120911/9365).

Comment: `s=>s.length-(s<0)` saves 6 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>30</s> 24 bytes

```
i->(""+i.abs()).length()
```

Assumes `i` is a `BigInteger`. Also, the type is contextualized, so no imports are required, as shown in the test code.

### Test

```
// No imports
class Pcg120897 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.util.function.ToIntFunction<java.math.BigInteger> f =
        // No full class declaration past here
        i->(""+i.abs()).length()
        // No full class declaration before here
      ;
    System.out.println(f.applyAsInt(new java.math.BigInteger("-1267650600228229401496703205376"))); // -(2^100)
    System.out.println(f.applyAsInt(new java.math.BigInteger("1267650600228229401496703205376"))); // (2^100)
  }
}
```

### Saves

- 30 -> 24 bytes : thanks to @cliffroot

Comment: `+""` instead of `.toString()` ?

Comment: +1 for providing sample code showing how this is invoked and for clarifying the type of `i` in your answer. I think more lambda answers should do this.

Answer (score 2):

## [V (vim)](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 20 bytes

```
:s/-
C<C-r>=strlen(<C-r>")
<esc>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/36pYX5fL2cZZt8jOtrikKCc1TwPMUdLkskktTrb7/1/X3MLyv24ZAA)

Remove minuses(if any), cut the line, and get its length.

Not sure if I need the `<esc>` at the end.

Comment: I don't think you need the final <esc>, at that point the solution is there, no need to exit from insert mode

Answer (score 2):

## [Risky](https://github.com/Radvylf/risky), 2 bytes

```
!?}*
```

[Try it online!](https://radvylf.github.io/risky?p=WyIhP30qIiwiWy0zMzEwNzYzODE1Mzg0NjI5MTgyOW5dIiwwXQ)

```
! length
?     input
}   base convert
*     10
```

Answer (score 2):

## [FALSE](https://github.com/somebody1234/FALSE), 14 bytes

```
^45=[1+^~][]#.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0vMKU79/z/OxNQ22lA7ri42OlZZ7/9/XRNTAA)

Explanation:
If first character is '-' (ascii code 45), then push -1. Else push 0. Add 1 to number on stack until EOF character is reached.

Answer (score 1):

## C++, <s>80</s> 76 bytes

```
#include<string>
int main(int,char**c){printf("%d",strlen(c[1])-(*c[1]<46));}
```

Prints the length of the argument, minuses 1 if the first character is a minus because `bool` guarantees conversion to `1` if `true` or `0` if `false`

- 4 bytes thanks to @Squidy for pointing out I can use `<46` instead of `=='-'`, and to deference the array instead of `[]`

Comment: You could shave off 4 bytes by replacing `c[1][0]=='-'` with `*c[1]<46` since we can assume the input will always be a valid integer. (Unless prefixes other than '-' are allowed...)

Comment: @Squidy oh wow nice find! I racked my brain for ages trying to shorten this and never even came up with that! Thanks for the suggestion, and especially for signing up to PCCG to let me know!

Comment: -1 byte by replacing `(*c[1]<46)` with `45/ *c[1]`, note the whitespace is necessary, otherwise it would be parsed as the start of a comment

Answer (score 1):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 10 bytes (non-competing)

```
 /d/
O@IHc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6@gn6LP5e/g6ZH8/7@uiSkA)

This is a non-competing solution, because at the time this challenge was posted the command `c` was bugged in the official (and only :D) interpreter. Martin Ender fixed it in the meanwhile, so this now works.

#### Explanation

The instruction pointer passes through the two mirrors (`/`) multiple times, so it may be a bit difficult to follow. I'll try to explain it as clearly as I can, using cardinal directions (e.g. N is up, SW is down to the left...).
I'll call `/1` the leftmost mirror, and `/2` the rightmost one.

```
Command    Direction    Comment
               E        Execution starts from the upper-left corner going right
   /1        E → SE     Passing through the mirror changes direction and switches
                        to ordinal mode (string operations)
   I        SE → NE     Push the input string to the stack, then bounce against
                        the bottom of the code
   /2       NE → S      Back to cardinal mode (numeric operations)
   H           S        Pop n, push abs(n). Execution wraps from bottom to top
   /2        S → SE     Ordinal mode again
   c        SE → NW     Pop s, push each char of s separatedly. Bounce against
                        the bottom right corner
   /2       NW → W      Cardinal mode
   d           W        Push the depth of the stack (which is now equal to 
                        the number of characters in abs(input))
   /1     W → NW → SW   Pass through the mirror, then bounce agains the top
   O        SW → NE     Output the result, then bounce on the bottom left corner
   /1       NE → S      Last mirror, I promise
   @           S        Terminate execution
```

Answer (score 1):

## REXX 22 Bytes

```
arg "-" a
say length(a)
```

Explanation:
There is no distinction in Rexx between numbers and strings. The action you perform is what defines the type. The "typing" applies just to that action and can change at any time.

So, here the number (say -20) is treated as a string. The "arg" instruction (short for parse arg) tells Rexx to search for the first "-" and then put everything after it in the variable "a". If "-" is not found then everything goes in "a".

[Try it here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_rexx_online.php)

REXX [functions](http://www.rexxinfo.org/html/functions.html) and [instructions](http://www.rexxinfo.org/html/instructions.html)

Answer (score 1):

## [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html), 78 bytes

Imperative style:

```
$(eval T=$1)$(foreach D,$(shell seq 9),$(eval T=$(subst $D,? ,$T)))$(words $T)
```

Functional style, 113 bytes:

```
$(eval 2?=$(shell seq 9))$(if $2,$(call $0,$(subst $(word 1,$2),? ,$1),$(wordlist 2,$(words $2),$2)),$(words $1))
```

Pure Make, 83 bytes:

```
$(eval T=$1)$(foreach D,0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9,$(eval T=$(subst $D,? ,$T)))$(words $T)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 15 bytes

```bash
wc -L<<<${1//-}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@1@erKDrY2Njo1JtqK@vW/v//39dQyNjE1MzcwtLAA)

Deletes `-` from input as array, and otputs length of longest line (wc -c returns one char more than length)

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic (TI-84 Plus CE, OS 5.2+), 6 bytes

```
length(toString(abs(Ans
```

TI-Basic is a tokenized language; `length(` and `toString(` are two bytes each.

`Ans` is used as implicit input; the last (only) line's value is implicitly returned.

Pretty simple, takes the absolute value to get rid of a minus sign, converts to string, returns the length of the string.

A 6-byte mathematical approach that doesn't work for 0:

```
1+log(abs(Ans
```

Comment: Which calculators have `toString(`?

Comment: @kamoroso94 TI-84 Plus CE

Answer (score 1):

## awk, 22 bytes

```
$1=length($1<0?-$1:$1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/awk#@69iaJuTmpdekqGhYmhjYK@rYmilYqj5/7@usREA)

[All test cases](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxdA2JzUvvSRDQ8XQxsBeV8XQSsVQ8/9/XRNTBS5DI1MTCwMjMy5jY0MDczNjC0NTYwsTMyNLQwsjSy5dIwMg4DIAAA)

Comment: You can save one byte by using `sqrt($1^2)` to take the absolute value. [TIO](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxdA2JzUvvSRDo7iwqERDxTDOSFPz/39dE1MFLkMjUxMLAyMzLmNjQwNzM2MLQ1NjCxMzI0tDCyNLLl0jAyDgMgAA).

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript, 23 bytes

```
x=>`${x<0?-x:x}`.length
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
A‘l⁵Ċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@/4qGFGzqPGrUe6/v83NTEzMTUzMTP9DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 13 bytes

```
n->#digits(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#DYlNCoAgFAav8lGbhCfo8ydb5EWiRRCFECLVptObAwMDc2BGzTL2ezrT@wxZ1K2U6xsyZES5U35bdojNo11BWKR1BM3OBsWeYIxWozdBOxOs50kHngiSVYOgVlF/)

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 15 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vba
?[Len(Abs(A1))]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Bound](https://github.com/HoofedEar/Bound), 4 bytes

```
ib_,
```

Explanation:

```
i # Get user input
b # Separate each digit of the top element into individual elements
_ # Put the total number of elements onto the stack
, # Remove all but the top element from the stack
```

Bound then prints the stack at the end of execution, so you can then see the result.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##1Vrrdho3EP7NPoVM6hpiTADnSkPapLnU57RJT5Km59RxOWIRoGZZbSUtl94eqg/SV3JnJO2yy26IHeIk5o@xLjPfjOYqES31RISHp6d8Ggmpif0T8IHnBtRSJV/HgUiHp1RPku@ShkMx9UZSTIlQzQimHB3ym@BhY0AVC@mUNVQUcM0W2vNePXr@4ujZU9Ij1Vmr2Wl2ql4YTwOuNA612p3D6zdu3rp9p@p5QzYCbjys@fWuV/Fh3m9KFgXUZ7UqqTZItVr3KkrE0mcweexPqCQjIYn5wkPin2SmkUVNshmTig1rdrgO@wMWjgE2LGBhMuxVZkChR/b2gICm/hskf@J5lfmEB4y4LTs90gJgFS2X@Kfix1KyEOWwZJqRiGpAq8IWPos0OQqHbPFISiHN8oFk9A3QrPARSbcCz@Zel1whz2IdxXAIyB1XR5KHumb@rZds2jeb7g@HXHMR4gZYYCQyO8i9HukYrjjOFQ9hPAQ9munjg/ZJAxSm6wQOtGS646YthVRg@FCUFhelwuJnUDpqR2gUsXBYG5B9Qt2M08/LZcRW6kGFilDzMGYl8h4YeV/EAy2pf2lEPthG5KtG5B/iQHPwJp9eGqmvnl3qjbiVllvjBg3qCUNS5RK4eaC1tSzFE9y1JyiGcSAuxcntbiPtNSPtQz7jQ9YgUsSAO44ugdyY4Zo@4wFo4Bpo4DzGm6z6hUmBoitw0rMq7PXrEo0NxfzivJx8YKWNAiHkR9bar0ZpP4o5k5cjGm4VQq7YvPd7TCUrFbd9BnHPKk8OOUXknfdHfs8gfwJFj2YSgiz9TJMXcIZTugeHlOzO66GdLGSBYuVLWu@vpbtGS98zpT57Fd39RCrqGRUdhZqNwZC@FdOISq7EZ60rwP1plPWX7QsGSgSxZmRGg/hjx42Bqp09GxQl2DESPIYqX0hOg48L3ma1hPdWcoxdnoqMuSk6wyoTDkRuksi2oVmQRcJPDOHntjEmGhiYUyZzDj0qEkB@fsA2c4JxXLuDTa@TpqCbnGpgtRtOe@Uitq9suprTyADTc0FYwKYwrTa5a3oyeHxezrnQL70UDM7DzCA70sERWgKm4RQ1FaB7GgRkAA02wNqEJO3@U3YnJZS/cZTN5cKqZ38b0ZTq2p2EWVd2xF8Y@grvVWz3ci4GuG8j@aEhr2MZGvJ4UtyFV/grCDU3Ktt6Xs56/ImsZeyrFNbrPYPrJcCxNzqKgH@BskAaAJk0aefGhH2kw1QaAnJAhRwaty/CUwbdz5JDXBXWkhLj3haWWqqm0kOg2pwj/dUyCzGTKkqWysxyXF@E/sLGIrxSUha7O/YPhD9zWVUKOpnPIy3i/NP6ldBQM2bx4ekj5ICNNmJN3MByaXdPyL773m2X@fHf7@An@XhyDoYHOY4HpSx/Wg9KIxqo5eYomWV23MVwd7wwF58LTCkWA2xamBvKMqbPk5QBxbgRLGQLDc41nWKuYNBdBInIq3yyrf@X@hqi7iNqGwppOGbQaRyQdj0tlzIZ293mJr5p/1tZGHzKb3OzOXvtFjaftYuq6hpVQZU54CFTqUqymQx1DeNLAj1ZEjjVJehFEx8c1I2RSoxz71/f@DamQDCBdCGiJRGj84SVHLJM5Cgy@jJhpFYnYF4g2mizYYMA@CBWfMaCJamxRXT/6UNVvxDrBeIwbK223SB0v50xa56aNSxLrTl/AmXy/WOd0zyt8D/YKuOTQASbzMq@xjTVJB6NAvb2t4JwpUBDO57iWWHssfkgfEeR4bSmIUwGIH7Ly0ls1jlp84rlOYW6/fs9wvOVVlkoC4XOUlpYSidFyzFEy4Q@cl2jL11Ed6bprNRyuhAjWbtF2YfYVoLvob37Y58cH8ZenChC/NqGwgmzZ1KKEGo0KGfDCwGKrTQlu6SDaFrlHpU4YLaZXu@li5INjGQP8EFOERpRqbOFsC2CFYsklgUbA/yHSIeruDGlEQbphg3Oto@unyOS1OxlkgAxYojbAbmYKIhPcOi5L2VynTuWIo7c@yl@xGikmE5jxZqYhUfZ7uruxNBOEzVCNC1qfS8dc8zSOJLhB2PtZCx3u5JCfgzFlklmRVAmqLcaxNLKqD3/tpuOILdUEotpddNbWpYUD6yfvOLaoiyeDqAFA/9aVRqZ2KySEu2dkTpnKasVZQi4vaVlhhc@QGNmCBOj95wJmCkrflqIFEoLd1niSolXWENmaom3VBIgoPs5gFlWIOrWGey2i6h7a2/jHpDr9/FnB/0@ylTt9/FXBP1@tZssrfYemMeVXdWrQkBxv0kASokGoamicjyr436jRPvwjxbeXb3GG/l8MWSpSqr//UuqiZfZGQDAFlxXrdj20X9t3s05bN@xIBANMhcyGO5YYivjtb@HgI0wnow6BAnoY3Nlslp4enp42G7dunl4u33j8Pb1m5077dudO6d80G/8Dw)

Answer (score 1):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 5 bytes

```
"-"-,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X0lXSVfn/38DAA)

```
"-"-    # Remove all "-" in the input
    ,   # Get the length of the string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 4 bytes

```apl
≢∘⍕|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P@1R24RHnYsedcx41Du15v@jvqlAgTQFQyNjE1MuGO/QejD/PwA)

Answer (score 1):

## BRASCA, 15 bytes

```
iM:45S=[xx0]x!n
```

[Try it online!](https://sjoerdpennings.github.io/brasca-online/?code=iM%3A45S%3D%5Bxx0%5Dx!n&stdin=-24)

### Explanation

```
i                - Turn the ascii characters 0-9 to numbers
 M:45S=[  0]     - Move the bottom of the stack to the front and check if it's a minus
        xx       - If so: remove the minus
            x    - Remove any excess items on the stack
             !n  - Print the length as a number
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Whispers v2](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/Whispers), 39 bytes

```
> Input
>> |1|
>> "2"
>> #3
>> Output 4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8/ILC5ILSo2@v/fTsEzr6C0hMvOTqHGsAZEKRkpgShlYxDpX1oClFUw@f9f18QUAA)

Boring answer. Get input, absolute value, convert to string, return length.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arn](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn) `-s`, [2 bytes](https://github.com/ZippyMagician/Arn/wiki/Carn)

```
.|
```

[Try it!](https://zippymagician.github.io/Arn?code=Lnw=&input=LTQ1CjEyNTQ4MDI2CjMzMTA3NjM4MTUzODQ2MjkxODI5Ci0yMDAwMAow&flags=cw==)

Take absolute value, `-s` takes size. Implicit casting.

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 20 bytes

```powershell
$args|% *m '-'|% Le*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNydFNzi9K/a@SZlv9XyWxKL24RlVBK1dBXVcdyPBJ1fpfy8WlppKmoGtibGZobGRs@P8/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 7 bytes

```julia
ndigits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvs/LyUzPbOk@H9JanFJsYKtQjSXrokpl6GRqQmXoYG5mbGFqbGFApeRARAocBlw6RpaAMWBCMQEYwMuS0suXSCO5eIqKMrMK8nJ09OAmKZna6eQBuVoav4HAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 2 bytes

```
ȧL
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C8%A7L&inputs=-20000&header=&footer=)

```
 L # Length of...
ȧ  # Absolute value of...
   # Implicit input
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `project-euler.common`, 13 bytes

```
number-length
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0tMLskv@h8a7OnnbqVQUJSflZpcoptampNapJecn5ubnwcUTC0pqSwoyswrUbDm4tI1Mf2fV5qblFqkm5Oal16S8V/vPwA)

Comment: this has to be the only language with project euler builtins

Comment: @Razetime Factor's policy of including nearly every contribution with the base language is nice in some ways!

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 17 bytes

```
{#$$[x<0;x*-1;x]}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.bitbucket.io/k#eJxLs6pWVlGJrrAxsK7Q0jW0roit5eJKU9A1MVXAAPoKdgpGQElDI1MTCwMjMwxJC6CksbGhgbmZsYWhqbGFiZmRpaGFkSVEpwHIXCMDIMBirilQEl0cLmmokF+kYAAAz5geRg==)

Can't handle big numbers correctly, e.g. `33107638153846291829`. Still decent though.

Answer (score 1):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 11 bytes

```
{#($x)^"-"}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6pW1lCp0IxT0lWq5eJKi9Y1MY0FUoZGpiYWBkZmILaxsaGBuZmxhaGpsYWJmZGloYWRJUhc18gACEAsg1gAb+UQ5A==)

Easy.

Explanation:

```
{#($x)^"-"}    Main function. Takes x as input
  ($x)         x as string
      ^"-"     Without string literal "-" (Remove negative symbol)
 #             Length
```

Comment: You can take input as a string and change `($x)` to `x`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$2\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 1.646 bytes

```
LA
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJMQSIsIi0xIl0=)

```
LA
L  # Length of
 A # The absolute value of the input
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fourier, 30 bytes

```
I~S<0{1}{-2*S~S}S{0}{S^~S}SL^o
```

[**Try it on FourIDE!**](https://beta-decay.github.io/editor/?code=SX5TPDB7MX17LTIqU35TfVN7MH17U15-U31TTF5v)

Fourier doesn't have strings, so it uses logs instead. Bytes are wasted on supporting zero and negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 6 bytes

```
nGU0<-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@5/nHmpgo/v/v7qusbGhgbmZsYWhqbGFiZmRpaGFkaU6AA)

#### Explanation

```
n     % Implicitly input a string. Push its length
G     % Push input again
U     % Convert to number (floating-point double). Although integers with absolute
      % value exceeding 2^53 cannot be represented exactly, the sign is correct
0<    % Is it negative?
-     % Subtract. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge](https://github.com/catseye/Befunge-93), 35 bytes

```
77*~`!1+:v
~0`#@    ># !#. #- #2_1+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge#@29urlWXoGiobVXGVWeQoOygAAR2ygqKynoKyroKykbxhtr//@saGhubAwA)

```
77*~`!            add 49 to the stack and see if that is less than 50 (ascii for
                  '-') 
1+:v              if there is a -, don't count it. Add 1 so we don't
                  have a zero at the top of the stack. Move down.
># !#. #- #2_1+   move right and add one to the total. (Will remove later)
~0`#@             Loop back around and take an input and make sure it is not end of 
                  the string (-1, so we make sure it is > 0)
># !#. #- #2_1+   check to see if there was an input. If there was, add one to the 
                  total. If not, move left. Subtract 2 because we added 1 at two 
                  different locations. Print output and end program.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bean](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean), 20 bytes

#### Hexdump:

```
00000000: 2650 80d3 d080 a05d 2080 0921 8181 0020  &P.ÓÐ. ] ..!... 
00000010: 8001 dc64                                ..Üd
```

#### JavaScript equivalent:

```
a.match(/\d/g).length;
```

#### Explanation:

Implicitly takes input as a decimal string in `a` and implicitly outputs the length of the match, which is all the decimal digits in the string. Returns `1` for input of `0`.

[See Demo](https://patrickroberts.github.io/bean/#h=JlCA09CAoF0ggAkhgYEAIIAB3GQ=&i=LTEwMA==&f=0&w=1).

## [Bean](https://github.com/patrickroberts/bean), 22 bytes

#### Hexdump:

```
00000000: 2aa0 1f26 4ccc d3a0 8043 53a0 802d 2043  * .&LÌÓ .CS .- C
00000010: 9125 398b 253a                           .%9.%:
```

#### JavaScript equivalent:

```
with(Math)((log10(abs(A))^0)+1);
```

#### Explanation:

Implicitly takes input as a decimal integer in `A`, takes the absolute value, then log-base-10, XORs with `0`, then adds `1`.

When `A` is `0`, the returned value of `log10()` is `-Infinity`, and `-Infinity ^ 0` is `0` in JavaScript, so the returned value for `0` is `1`.

[See Demo](https://patrickroberts.github.io/bean/#h=KqAfJkzM06CAQ1OggC0gQ5ElOYslOg==&i=LTEwMA==&f=0&w=1).

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 7 bytes

```
#@":@**
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/j#U9JTT1OwtVJQV9BRMFCwAmJdPQXnIB0ft//KDkpWDlpa/zW58kAqjEzNuEqSQSwNnbpMKwcbK808rtTkjHwFjRorJSNNhXhDM4XYGKCsnkKapkJJ8n8A)

All the solutions I came up with:

```
0>.@>.10^.>:@(**)
[:#10&#.inv
#@-.&'-'
#@":@**
```

The first one is math, the second is base conversion, the third takes a string as input, and the shortest takes a number.

The current solution looks like this:

```
              ┌─ # 
        ┌─ @ ─┴─ ":
  ┌─ @ ─┴─ *       
──┴─ *
```

The parent root is a hook between the upper tine and the lower tine. The lower tine (`*`) is a monad that calculates magnitude. The upper tine is a composition:

```
         ┌─ # 
   ┌─ @ ─┴─ ":
@ ─┴─ *
```

This composes the upper tine (another composition) with `*`, in this case, a dyad. This is the dyad for multiplication. In the last tine:

```
   ┌─ # 
@ ─┴─ ":
```

This calculates format (`":`) then length (`#`).

In English form, this is "multiply `x` times the sign of `x`, then convert this to a string, then take the length of this string". Basically, `abs.toString.length`.

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 33 bytes

```
i=>Math.Abs(i).ToString().Length;
```

Comment: You need to fully qualify `Math` and you can save bytes by using `+""` instead of `ToString()`.

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 4 bytes

```
47>s
```

Inspired by [Martin's Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120898/36398): count how many characters have code point exceeding 47 (this excludes the minus sign).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@29iblf8/7@6rpEBEKgDAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Braingolf](https://github.com/gunnerwolf/braingolf), 2 bytes

```
dl
```

#### Explaination:

```
dl
    Implicit input from command-line args to stack
d   Pop last item from stack, split it into digits, and push each digit to the stack
 l  Push length of stack to the end of the stack
    Implicit output of last item on stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 48 + 3 ( `-a`) = 51 bytes

```
({}[((((()()()()())){}{})){}{}]){(<><>)}{}([]<>)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brain-flak#@69RXRutAQKaMKipWV1bXQshYzWrNWzsbOw0gWyN6Fgg4/9/Y2NDA3MzYwtDU2MLEzMjS0MLI8v/uokA)

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 28 bytes

```c#
s=>s.Replace("-","").Length;
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 24 bytes

```c#
n=>$"{n>0?n:-n}".Length;
```

Inspired from [@DomHastings answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121043/38550).

Answer (score 0):

## [Chaincode](https://code.sololearn.com/cAw9mAl5Q9AX/?ref=app), 5 bytes

```
pqL_+
```

### Explanation

```
pqL_+ print(
    +   succ(
   _      floor(
  L        log_10(
pq           abs(
               input())))))
```

Answer (score 0):

## C, 43 bytes

```
f(char*s){printf("%d",strlen(s)-(*s==45));}
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#NY3NCoMwEITPyVMsgUISDcT404jkSUoPYhWFVoNJT5LH7tkmhe5h@BhmZ86JDnO/c8cOuy@rnyi5PEju/P4cV@qYoNwZU9WMdeF89ctKGT4wSj/A/ei8u93BwAFEVDXJgRSqrrRUTeKyLOS1KXVRl7pqVFto1SZfKBkvURIJofs3chtx2nag1vzaO4gW2CxjGMVdNFFuWcwg@/aOEpI44IDPz7qJoR/m8Qs)

Answer (score 0):

## T-SQL, 38 bytes

```
CREATE PROC l @ BIGINT AS PRINT LEN(@)
```

Usage:

```
EXECUTE l @ = 9999999999
```

Comment: If it's a negative int, it returns an extra number in the result. Probably need to add `LEN(ABS(@))`

Answer (score 0):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 26 bytes

Replaces all occurrences of `'-'` with the empty string `''` and get length with `#`.

```lua
print(#(...):gsub('-',''))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/lua#@19QlJlXoqGsoaenp2mVXlyapKGuq66jrq6p@f//f10jAyAAAA)

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 9 bytes + 3 for -F flag=12 bytes

```
say@F-/-/
```

Run like `perl -F -E 'say@F-/-/'`. Takes a single number from stdin without a trailing newline. Can add the `-l` flag at the cost of an extra byte if you would rather have it accept a trailing newline.

The `-F` flag auto splits stdin into the array `@F`. In scalar context, `@F` evaluates to the length of the array, which is the number of characters in `$_` (which comes from stdin). `/-/` in a numerical context evaluates to 1 if `$_` has a minus sign in it or 0 if `$_` does not have a minus sign in it, so `@F-/-/` evaluates to the number of non-minus sign characters (i.e. the number of digit characters) read from stdin.

Answer (score 0):

## C, <s>71</s> 38 bytes

- **-33 bytes** *FelipeNardiBatista*

[**Try Online**](http://ideone.com/83rza5)

```c
f(char*t){return*t?(*t>'-')+f(t+1):0;}
```

Comment: why don't you just `return` the number?

Comment: [golfed to 38 bytes](http://ideone.com/83rza5)

Comment: @FelipeNardiBatista changed now, thx

Comment: [35 bytes](https://ideone.com/6SCMWo)

Answer (score 0):

## Swift, 138 bytes

You would think there would be an easier way to do this.

```swift
import Foundation;var d:(String)->Int={return $0.trimmingCharacters(in:CharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted).characters.count}
```

You can try it [here](http://swift.sandbox.bluemix.net/#/repl/591d8b5def829376a284fe07)

Un-golfed:

```swift
import Foundation // Import the Foundation module

var d:(String)->Int={ // Create a closure that takes in a String and returns an Int

    return // Return the following

    $0.trimmingCharacters(in:  // Removes all characters in the following CharacterSet

        CharacterSet(charactersIn:"0123456789").inverted // Create a CharacterSet with all characters that are not digits

    ).characters.count // Get the length of the resulting String
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 23 Bytes

```
f(x)==#(abs(x)::String)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Desmos, 31 bytes

```
g=abs(a)
f(a)=floor(log(g+0^g))
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9iyg46sdjj)

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 101 bytes

```
@set/pi=
@set o=-1&if %i:~,1%==- set o=-2
:l
@set/ao+=1&if %i%. neq . set i=%i:~,-1%&goto:l
@echo %o%
```

---

#### 89 bytes

```
@set/pi=
@if %i% lss 0 set/ai=-%i%
:l
@set/ao+=1&if %i% gtr 9 set/ai/=10&goto:l
@echo %o%
```

Only works for 32-bit numbers.

Answer (score 0):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/math_golf.txt), 2 [bytes](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf/blob/master/code_page.py)

```
±£
```

Input as integers.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///QxkOL///XNTHlMjQyNbEwMDLjMjY2NDA3M7YwNDW2MDEzsjS0MLLk0jUyAAIuAwA)

I'm actually surprised builtin `£` works on integers. I was expecting I would need an explicit cast, since that's the case with a lot of MathGolf's builtins.

**Explanation:**

```python
±   # Get the absolute value of the (implicit) input-integer
 £  # Pop and get the length of this integer
    # (after which the entire stack is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
ìl
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7Gw&input=LTIwMDAw)

```
ìl     :Implicit input of integer
ì      :Convert to digit array
 l     :Length
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 2 bytes

```
Al
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWixxzlhQnJRdDuQuW6BoaGUPYAA)

`l`ength of the `A`bsolute value of the implicit input.