# How long is my number: Restricted Version

Tags: code-golf, number, integer

#### *Find the original challenge [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120897/how-long-is-my-number)*

### Challenge

Given an integer, `Z` in the range `-2^31 < Z < 2^31`, output the number of digits in that number (in base 10).

### Rules

You must not use any string functions (in the case of overloading, you must not pass a string into functions which act as both string and integer functions). You are not allowed to store the number as a string.

All mathematical functions are allowed.

You may take input in any base, but the output must be the length of the number in base 10.

Do not count the minus sign for negative numbers. Number will never be a decimal.

Zero is effectively a leading zero, so it can have zero *or* one digit.

### Examples

```
Input > Output

-45 > 2
1254 > 4
107638538 > 9
-20000 > 5
0 > 0 or 1
-18 > 2
```

### Winning

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: I assume no array functions either?

Comment: @Cyoce Yes, no array functions

Comment: So if a language only accepts input as a string, it's invalid for this challenge, right?

Comment: @EngineerToast Yes, very much so

Comment: I'm removing the restricted source tag because while this is a restriction it is not a real source restriction in that it is not computer tractable.

Answer (score 10):

### Mathematica, 13 bytes

```
IntegerLength
```

[Well...](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/120902/8478)

Comment: According to https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3605/14732 this makes this question a duplicate.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Well, this is a slightly trickier case, because the challenge is effectively a duplicate in some languages but not at all on others.

Comment: Most answers there can be just copied over to here.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I'd have to go and count, but I believe the majority of answers on the previous challenge used string processing which is not an option here.

Comment: Meh, I lost the count 3 times. But seems to actually be around 30-45% of the answers. Those can be just copied over.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 30 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x and-~f(abs(x)/10)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#DcFBDoMgEADAs/sKjnDYyKJYYuJjVpRIotRYGzn5a8@0MyUMK2/jxCL3WXCa8A6Sx4/MqiatyrXEdRbUQ7UfMZ0iyJj27ymVKthaIGNbIP3qGmcbB2j0H2hAck96o2e/zD8)

Comment: @Notts90 I do, because it is referenced inside.

Answer (score 7):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>5</s> 3 bytes

```
ì l
```

[Try it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=7CBs&input=LTQy)

Comment: I pushed a fix that makes the `a` unnecessary -- 5 minutes before the challenge was posted :-) Unfortunately, that means it'll only work on the online interpreter. ([test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.4&code=7CBs&input=LTQz))

Comment: Awesome. Well done ninja'ing the question ; )

Answer (score 7):

### JavaScript (ES6), 19 bytes

```js
f=n=>n&&f(n/10|0)+1

console.log(f(-45))       // 2
console.log(f(1254))      // 4
console.log(f(107638538)) // 9
console.log(f(-20000))    // 5
console.log(f(0))         // 0
console.log(f(-18))       // 2
```

Comment: do we count "f="? lots of the other languages here present the function definition by itself.

Comment: @Sparr This is a recursive function that references itself. So in this special case, yes, we count `f=`.

Answer (score 5):

My answer from [the other challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121002/62131) still works:

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 1 byte

```
l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@5/z/3@8oZGxien/KAA)

The `l` builtin is overloaded, but on integers, it takes the number of digits of the integer, ignoring sign.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>3</s> 2 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to Leaky Nun*

```
DL
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@/i8///f11DCwA)

#### Explanation

```
 L    Length of
D     Decimal expansion of input argument. Works for negative values too
```

Comment: [`DL`](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@/i8///f11DCwA)?

Comment: I was trying to do this. But I couldn't find what I needed on the code page :(

Comment: "length" of an integer, using the same function that gives the length of a string, really feels like a string function...

Comment: Not lenght of an integer, but of a _list_ of its digits (obtained with `D`). The challenge says: _in the case of overloading, you must not pass a string into functions which act as both string and integer functions_ This answer follows that rule: I'm not passing a string

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 bytes

```apl
⌈10⍟1+|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///P@1R24RHPR2GBo965xtq1wAFFAy50hSMjIGEJRAbGoAII2NjCAUhzS0sjYwB)

Explanation:

```apl
⌈10⍟1+|
⌈        ⍝ round up the
 10⍟     ⍝ log10 of...
    1+   ⍝ incremented
      |  ⍝ absolute value of input
```

If format is allowed: 4 bytes - `≢⍕∘|`

Comment: [`≢10∘⊤` in Extended](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNrShJzUtJTfn/P@1R24RHnYsMDR51zHjUtQQooGDIlaZgZAwkLIHY0ABEGBkbQygIaW5haWQMAA "APL (Dyalog Extended) – Try It Online"), if you are so inclined.

Answer (score 3):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 16 bytes

```
/O
\I@/Hwa:].$Kq
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/alice#@6/vzxXj6aDvUZ5oFaun4l34/7@uiSkA)

#### Explanation

```
/O
\I@/...
```

This is simply a framework for numerical input→mathematical processing→numerical output.

The rest of the code is the real algorithm:

```
Hwa:].$Kq
H            Compute absolute value
 w   .$K     While the result is not zero do:
  a:           divide the number by 10
    ]          move the tape head one cell forward
        q    Get the position of the tape head
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Chaincode](https://code.sololearn.com/cAw9mAl5Q9AX/?ref=app), 5 bytes

```
pqL_+
```

#### Note: This is exactly the same code as that from the other challenge

### Explanation

```
pqL_+ print(
    +   succ(
   _      floor(
  L        log_10(
pq           abs(
               input())))))
```

Answer (score 3):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 1 byte

```
Z
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#izc0Mjb5H/W/4D8A)

---

Not using a builtin, 18 bytes:

```
[d10/d0!=F]dsFxz1-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#izc0Mjb5H51iaKCfYqBo6xabUuxWUWWo@7/gPwA)

Answer (score 3):

## Java 8, <s>61</s> <s>59</s> <s>39</s> <s>37</s> 33 bytes

```java
n->(int)Math.log10(n<0?-n:n+.5)+1
```

-4 bytes thanks to *@MarkJeronimus*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY7PDoIwDMbvPEWPW8iWIaLEv0@AF4/GwxwTp1gIDBJjeHYcytXQtE3a/r58vctWsqLUeE8fvcplXUMiDb49AINWV1epNByG8bsARYaOdO02nSuXtZXWKDgAwhZ6ZLsBoYm0N54XWSAIbsSe4Qp9HlE/6NeeE5XNJXeiUdsWJoWn8yVHWxnMTmeQ9Gd6fNVWP3nRWF66k82RIFeEzSP6feIvEcyi@RQiloswjsJ4gmMz4WICmrqzYLTpvK7/AA)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->            // Method with integer as both parameter and return-type
  (int)        //  Convert the following double to an integer (truncating its decimals):
    Math.log10(//   The log_10 of:
      n<0?     //    If the input is negative:
          -n   //     Use its absolute value
         :     //    Else:
          n+.5)//     Add 0.5 to the input instead
  +1           //  And add 1 to the result at the end
```

Comment: 33: `n->(int)Math.log10(n<0?-n:n+.5)+1`

Comment: @MarkJeronimus Thanks! :)

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes

```r
function(x)max(ceiling(log10(abs(x))),0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpJCoUwEET3niLgphsMdGLiAB/voqJNQBNwAG@fH2Ot6r2qI/JPxvX28@WChwf38YF5cZvzDFtgRTBOZ/KIFWFkkMZiKQahCwalrclgXqC2qTtbd9n0yUhNKRltwq@RCIdQ76q@p45/)

Comment: I realize it's been 3 years, but here's a [38 byte](https://tio.run/##JYpRCoAgEET/O4UQwUpJrmkZRHepIAkqwQq6vZnO17w347wZmF@fc7k3e8JLsTymF3ZrkMM0X8HQiiEt6gK9ASYVzclIRGYAhZIR5A@8axutGh1NHwwTPCSiCpgaJ9YR/FdMT@E/ "R – Try It Online") version.

Answer (score 3):

### Pip, 14 bytes

```
LNABq/LNt//1+1
```

https://tio.run/##K8gs@P/fx8/RqVDfx69EX99Q2/D/f0MDczNjC1NjCwA

Explanation

```
LN              natural log of...      (change of base becasue this is the only log function they had)
  ABq           the absolute value of the input...
     /          divided by...
      LNt       the natural log of 10...   (change of base)
         //1    integer divided by 1 (no floor function)
            +1  added to 1
```

This was inspired by the Chaincode solution.

This could probably be optimized.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, nice first answer!

Answer (score 2):

## [S.I.L.O.S](https://github.com/rjhunjhunwala/S.I.L.O.S), 41 bytes

```
readIO
i|
lblb
i/10
a+1
if i b
printInt a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/silos#@1@Umpji6c@VWcOVk5STxJWpb2jAlahtyJWZppCpkMRVUJSZV@KZV6KQ@P//f11DA3MzYwtTYwsA)

Returns `1` for `0`.

Comment: Why is there no love for SILOS, its golfier than python for this challenge!

Answer (score 2):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org), 40 bytes

Port from my python answer

```lua
print(math.log10(math.abs(10*...)+1)//1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/lua#@19QlJlXopGbWJKhl5OfbmgAYSYmFWsYGmjp6elpahtq6usbav7//1/XxPRrXr5ucmJyRioA)

Answer (score 2):

## C, 27 bytes

[**Try Online**](http://ideone.com/N4UtSG)

```c
f(n){return n?1+f(n/10):0;}
```

**C (gcc), 22 bytes**

```c
f(n){n=n?1+f(n/10):0;}
```

**Using math, 29 bytes**

```c
f(n){return 1+log10(abs(n));}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>10</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes

-3 bytes from @ngn (see [Am I an insignificant array?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/143278/am-i-an-insignificant-array/221444#comment515993_221444))

```
#10\#!:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NStnQIEZZ0ep/mrquiamCoZGpiYKhgbmZsYWpsYWCrpEBECgYKOgaWvwHAA)

- `#!:` get the absolute value of the input (literally, take the count of the range of each value; e.g. `#!-2` -> `#-2 -1` -> `2`)
- `10\` "digit-ize" the input
- `#` take the count

A solution using `$` instead of `10\` save two bytes, but may be invalid given the question's rules.

Comment: -1 byte: ``#10\|/-:\``

Comment: Thanks, very neat use of monadic scan/converge!

Answer (score 2):

### ARM Thumb-2 (no div instruction, no libgcc), 30 bytes

Raw machine code:

```
2800 d00b bfb8 4240 2201 2100 3101 380a
dafc 3201 0008 280a daf7 0010 4770
```

Uncommented assembly:

```armasm
        .syntax unified
        .globl count_digits
        .thumb
        .thumb_func
count_digits:
        cmp     r0, #0
        beq     .Lret
        it      lt
        neglt   r0, r0
        movs    r2, #1
.Lcountloop:
        movs    r1, #0
.Ldivloop:
        adds    r1, #1
        subs    r0, #10
        bge     .Ldivloop
.Ldivloop_end:
        adds    r2, #1
        movs    r0, r1
        cmp     r0, #10
        bge     .Lcountloop
.Lcountloop_end:
        movs    r0, r2
.Lret:
        bx      lr
```

Returns 0 if 0.

#### Explanation

C function signature:

```c
int32_t count_digits(int32_t val);
```

First, we compare val to zero.

If it is zero, we return zero. If it is less than zero, we negate it.

```armasm
count_digits:
        cmp     r0, #0
        beq     .Lret
        it      lt
        neglt   r0, r0
```

Set up our digit counter for the outer loop.

```armasm
        movs    r2, #1
```

Now, a naïve subtraction based division loop

```armasm
        movs    r1, #0
.Ldivloop:
        adds    r1, #1
        subs    r0, #10
        bge     .Ldivloop
```

Increment the digits counter, then loop to the outer loop if we are still more than 10.

```armasm
.Ldivloop_end:
        adds    r2, #1
        movs    r0, r1
        cmp     r0, #10
        bge     .Lcountloop
```

Move the result into the return register and return.

```armasm
.Lcountloop_end:
        movs    r0, r2
.Lret:
        bx      lr
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](http://julialang.org/), 7 bytes

```julia
ndigits
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPifZvs/LyUzPbOk@H9JanFJsYKtQjSXrokpl6GRqQmXoYG5mbGFqbGFApeRARAocBlw6RpaAMWBCMQEYwMuS0suXSCO5eIqKMrMK8nJ09OAmKZna6eQBuVoav4HAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 46 bytes

```powershell
param($a)for($s=0;$a){$s+=!!($a=[int]$a/10)}$s
```

### Implementation Details

```powershell
param($a)              # Defines the input parameter
for($s=0;$a){          # Initialise the result to 0 and iterates while the parameter is not 0 
$s+=!!($a=[int]$a/10)  # Divides the parameter by 10 and increment the result variable
                       # by one if the result is not 0
}$s                    # Returns the result
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9Ba4NAEIXP66@YhGlRulI12lqCIJSeW0hvIQRjRtqi0e6utGD97dtJIm329N6b@d6wXftFSr9RXftlq8hilQ22K1TRuFh4Vatc1FmwZD2gvslmM46z9fvBbLC4DQNvRG1Hx8ldR8jc9eNEQuSddBglsYR4MsH93SJNFqmEh3PiRwE/CcnZsgqmQZieOjz4gSsYHIGHvtmRkoD03VFpaA8Z4HbJE0W6rw3ba6xg2uN8/bJ67LVpm@fdBwMbyLlGrPqyJK2P8MT59PlfypyYv5I2UBaa5se1v0LxdHH5Ahgd/ru1vw)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel, 26 bytes

```
=INT(LOG(A1^2+(A1=0))/2)+1
```

Log of the number squared / 2 is 1 byte shorter than `ABS`

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
int(log(1+10abs(Ans
```

Takes input in `Ans`.

-1 byte thanks to [MarcMush](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/98541/marcmush).

Comment: `int(log(1+10abs(Ans `

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

-3 thanks to ovs
-1 thanks to pizzapants

```python
lambda x:math.log10(abs(10*x)+1)//1
import math
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#NYzBbsIwEETP@CtWnOxiwBuSNkTiCNd@gMvBDqZxlcSR44j0w3sOdqvuYd@MZnbvp4@lVZ2@KZirToVm17pPFFTpkaJ4mdkG2X6PxHaD8wFSYwn@uyKrR2NbAxjVSnF9sv0wBcqSG0cTq3eqGNgeNAeaNAfNiJlrMwQ4v1/O3jtfCTJ42wdY35T9cpOe1mQ5colXsv0DCi6z6P6ZF7/ErMi5zFP@9nooi0PJ5THGmYjDZXElcQue/mCZLn56t61V3Zgn)

Comment: `lambda x:1+log10(abs(x)+.1)//1` for 48 bytes

Comment: `import math` and `math.log10` saves one byte

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 6 bytes

```
Ä>T.nî
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@4xS5EL@/wuv//dQ0NzM2MLUyNLQA) or [Try all tests](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#qymr/H@4xS5EL@/wuv@VSof3K1gpKNnr/Nc1MeUyNDI14TI0MDcztjA1tuDSNTIAAi4DLl1DCwA)

```
Ä      # Absolute value
 >     # Increment
  T.n  # Log base 10
     î # Round up
```

Comment: [`Ä>T.nî`](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#qymr/H@4xS5EL@/wuv@VSof3K1gpKNnr/Nc1MeUyNDI14TI0MDcztjA1tuDSNTIAAi4DLl1DCwA)

Answer (score 1):

## C#, <s>49</s> 56 bytes

```c#
namespace System.Math{n=>n==0?1:Floor(Log10(Abs(n))+1);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
A‘l⁵Ċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@/4qGFGzqPGrUe6/v83NTEzMTUzMTP9DwA)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 27 bytes

```
f=->x{x==0?0:1+f[x.abs/10]}
```

As a test:

```
tests = [[-45 , 2],
         [1254 , 4],
         [107638538 , 9],
         [-20000 , 5],
         [0 , 0 ],
         [-18 , 2]]

tests.each do |i, o|
  p f.call(i) == o
end
```

It outputs:

```
true
true
true
true
true
true
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-Minteger -p`, <s>26</s> 24 bytes

```perl
1while++$\*abs($_/=10)}{
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/9@wPCMzJ1VbWyVGKzGpWEMlXt/W0ECztvr/f11LS8t/@QUlmfl5xf91fU31DAwNgHRmXklqemrRf90CAA)

Answer (score 1):

## @yBASIC, 53 bytes.

```
_#=@_>.@_
_%=_%/(_#*_#+!.)_=_+!.GOTO(@_)+"_"*!_%@__?_
```

Input should be stored in variable _%

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 41 bytes

```
fn f(n:i32)->u8{n!=0&&return f(n/10)+1;0}
```

[Try it online!](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=d72062485bb32892aab46c26d8047ea0&version=stable)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 10 bytes

```
.xhs.l.aQT
```

[**Test suite**](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=.xhs.l.aQT&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=-45%0A1254%0A107638538%0A-20000%0A0%0A-18&debug=0)

Explanation:

```
.xhs.l.aQT  # Code
.xhs.l.aQTQ # With implicit variables
            # Print (implicit):
    .l   T  #   the log base 10 of:
      .aQ   #    the absolute value of the input
   s        #   floored
  h         #   plus 1
.x        Q #  unless it throws an error, in which case the input
```

Python 3 translation:

```
import math
Q=eval(input())
try:
    print(int(math.log(abs(Q),10))+1)
except:
    print(Q)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><>](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish), 12 bytes

```
SA:z+aSLS(PB
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvhv6Oju6Wrt7vc/2NGqSjsx2CdYI8Dp/39dE1MuQyNTEy5DA3MzYwtTYwsuXSMDIOCyhAIuXTjLgMuQS9fQAgA)

#### Example full program & How it works

```
1AGIE;GN
SA:z+aSLS(PB

1AGIE;GN
1AG       Register row 1 as function G
   IE;    Take input as int, halt if EOF
      GN  Call G and print the result as int

SA:z+aSLS(PB
SA            Absolute value
  :z+         Add 1 if zero
     aSL      Take log 10
        S(    Floor
          PB  Increment and return
```

Many math functions are prefixed with `S`, which made the code longer.

Adding 0.9 unconditionally (`9a,+`) and using ceiling (`S)`) is also possible with same byte count. Zero input yields 0 in this case.

Answer (score 1):

## AWK, 33 bytes

```
$1=int(log(($1?$1^2:1)^.5)/2.3)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzP/v9fxdA2M69EIyc/XUNDxdBexTDOyMpQM07PVFPfSM9YU9vw/39dE1MuQyNTEy5DA3MzYwtTYwsuXSMDIOAy4NI1tAAA)

Basically, this will print the integer part of the log base 10 of the input, plus one. `2.3` is a working approximation of natural log of 10. To deal with negative numbers, it takes the square root of the power of two. If input is zero, returns `1` instead, so the pattern is different from `0`, which would return false and would not be printed. Too many necessary workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 38 bytes

```r
f=function(x)`if`(x^2<100,1,1+f(x/10))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYrNCoAgEITvPYXQZaWi3U37gexRQgiULgVR4Nub2Zzm@2au6E10xj3Hdu/nAUHa3VkIK8@EWFNNlYPQEkoZPTRKy1IsggsPxFplUB/g0Hej7sZspmQaxpSMOuHfUJyXoG@l/8nxBQ)

Unusually for [R](https://www.r-project.org/), a recursive function seems to be shorter here than the [previous answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/164030/95126) using built-in functions (although this is mostly gained simply because we can skip `abs(x)` by using `x^2<100` as a condition instead)...

Answer (score 1):

## [Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/), 80 bytes

```
$(N):
ifeq ($(N),0)
	@echo 0
else
	@expr 1 + $(shell make N=$$(($(N)/10)))
endif
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y03MTv3/X0XDT9OKKzMttVBBA8TWMdDk4nRITc7IVzDgSs0pTgXxKgqKFAwVtBVUNIozUnNyFHKBWhX8bFVUNMB69A0NNDU1uVLzUjLT/v/3s7WwsAAA)

I'm posting this entry for two reasons...

First, it's a ridiculous way to get the number of digits. :)  It's recursively calling `make`, each time dividing the number by 10, and counting how many time that happens.

Second, it works on my Linux test system from the commandline (which is using `GNU Make 4.1`) but will not work at all on TIO (which appears to be using `GNU Make 4.2.1`).  So I'm really curious about that and would like to know if it works for other people?  It might just be that I don't know how to translate things like:

```
~/work/code-golf$ make N=888
3
```

to TIO's input format syntax?

Comment: I'm also not sure about how exactly arguments are managed by TIO, but you can make it work with bash: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvifmpyRr6D@X0XDT9OKKzMttVBBA8TWMdDk4nQASxpwpeYUp4J4FQVFCoYK2goqGsUZqTk5CrmJ2akKfrYqKhpgPfqGBpqamlypeSmZaf/VFezA8mmZOalcUIUWFhb//4MpAA "Bash – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 26 bytes

```
[ abs log10 >integer 1 + ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcyxCsIwFEbh3af4d0lJ2kaDgqu4uIiTOMRwWwttEpPbQcRnj8UzfOPprOOQyvVyOh93mCw//1Td7B0PwWfERMzvmAbPyPSayTvK2K8@EK2GqnULJbebxujGQNRyCRJCGXzLDfaRMYZeSRyWAfWUoLDGvUw2oio/)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
ȧ›∆τ⌈
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C8%A7%E2%80%BA%E2%88%86%CF%84%E2%8C%88&inputs=-2003&header=&footer=)

Thanks to the 05AB1E answer for providing me with an algorithm to port.

### Explained

```
ȧ›∆τ⌈
ȧ›      # abs(input) + 1
  ∆τ    # log_10(↑)
    ⌈   # ceil(↑)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
A⁺Ælṃ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPUElRTIlODElQkElQzMlODZsJUUxJUI5JTgzJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9LTEwJmZsYWdzPQ==)

```python
A⁺Ælṃ  # Implicit input
A      # Absolute value
 ⁺     # Increment it
  Æl   # Log base 10
    ṃ  # Ceiling
       # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, <s>3</s> 2 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Split on each number and get the length. Is this ok? I'm not using any string method implicitly

*thanks @The Empty String Photographer*

```
ìl
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=7Gw&input=MTAwMA)

Comment: [You don’t need the space for some strange reason…](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=7Gw&input=MTAwMA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 25 bytes

```perl6
{0 max.abs.log10.floor+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcHRCoMgFAbg@z3FT8TYCOWcyiZUe5UwyN0Yht5Mwme3vu/YghvKnp52LidhN39p1iid/zFJ67wPDecyPqJJqOoFp33VyztXsD5gEr0Ct6oH02fotOo0REs3EATr71gu)

Answer (score 1):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
⌈ₙ10+1⌵
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=RiDihpAg4o2c4oaYKOKWvcKs4oiKLCJhZWlvdSIpMQoKRiAiaSIKRiAiYXRlIgpGICJwb3RhdG8iCkYgImtzYm9lanFmZ2NyYXV4cHdpdnR6bmRsaG15Igo=)

```
⌈ₙ10+1⌵
      ⌵  # absolute value
    +1   # increment
 ₙ10     # log base ten
⌈        # ceiling
```

Answer (score 0):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
|OYAn
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@1/jH@mY9/@/rqEFAA)

#### Explanation

```
|     % Implicitly input a number. Absolute value
OYA   % Convert to array of decimal digits
n     % Length. Implicitly display
```

Answer (score 0):

## PowerShell, <s>52</s> 51 Bytes

```
$m=[math];$m::Floor($m::Log10($m::Abs($args[0])))+1
```

Thanks to Felipe for both fixing the Issue with Log10, and providing a 1byte save.

Any `System.Math` calls are extremely expensive in PowerShell.

Uses the method of getting the Log10 of the Abs Value of the input, and rounding that up.

Comment: you should use `Floor()+1`. `Ceil()` fails for for powers of 10

Comment: use `$m::Log10(...` to save a byte

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 27 bytes

```matlab
@(x)fix(log10(abs(x+~x)))+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/octave#S7PV09P776BRoZmWWaGRk59uaKCRmFSsUaFdV6Gpqalt@D9NQ9fEVJMrTcPQyNQETBuYmxlbmBpbgDi6RgZAAGKBCV1DC83/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 23 Bytes

```php
<?=-~log10(abs($argn));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#s7EvyCjgUkksSs@zVTJQsuayt/tvY2@rW5eTn25ooJGYVKwBltTUtP7/HwA)

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 25 bytes

```
≈abs(:)>=1|b=b+1┘a=a/z}?b
```

This divides the input by 10, and keeps track of how many times we can do this until `N` < 1.

Explanation:

```
≈abs(:)>=1| : gets cmd line input, 
            ≈ starts a while loop,
            abs() is literal QBasic code and is for cases with negative n
            | is the terminator to the WHILE-condition
b=b+1       Keep track of the # of divisions        
┘           Syntactic line break
a=a/z       Divide a by 10 (z==10 in QBIC)
}           End WHILE-loop body
?b          PRINT b
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), 50 bytes

```bash
a=$1;until [ $a -eq 0 ];{ let i++ a=a/10;};echo $i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@59oq2JoXZpXkpmjEK2gkqigm1qoYKAQa52Sr5CTWqKQqa2tkGibqG9oABTJS7VOTc7IV1DJ/P//v66hkbGJqRkA)

No string/array command, only count digits by integer division.

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 33 bytes

```ruby
->x{1+Math.log10(x.abs+0.1).to_i}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#S7ON@a9rV1FtqO2bWJKhl5OfbmigUaGXmFSsbaBnqKlXkh@fWfu/oLSkWCFNLzkxJ0dBJR4sqFCekZmTqpCeWlL8X9fElMvQyNSEy9DA3MzYwtTYgkvXyAAIuAy4dA0tAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html), 6 bytes

```
length
```

Built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 8 bytes

```
;0=+A╥Lu
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@29tYKvt@GjqUp/S//8NAA)

Explanation:

```
;0=+A╥Lu
;0=       is input equal to 0?
   +      add 1 if input is 0, else add 0
    A     absolute value
     ╥L   log base 10, floor
       u  increment
```

This program effectively calculates `floor(log10(x))+1`. To deal with `log(0)` being undefined (actually it returns `(-inf+nanj)` which is a special way of saying it's undefined), the input is incremented if it is `0` prior to computing the length. Thus, `0` is considered to have a length of `1`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 13 bytes

```
n->#digits(n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pari-gp#S1OwVfifp2unnJKZnllSrJGn@T@xoCCnUiNPQddOoaAoM68EyFRSsAPiNKCspo5CtK6JqY6CoZGpCZA0MDcztjA1ttBR0DUyAAIdBSDSNbSI1fwPAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `l`, 1 byte

```
ȧ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2&c=1#WyJsIiwiIiwiyKciLCIiLCIxMDc2Mzg1MzgiXQ==)

This is why restricting built-ins is a bad idea. The `l` flag outputs the length of the top of the stack implicitly, which I don't think is a "function" - it's a feature of the language variant, not a function.

The `ȧ` simply gets the absolute value because `-` is counted in the size.

Answer (score 0):

## [jamforth](https://github.com/ambyshframber/jamforth/), 6 bytes

```forth
UWIDTH
```

I'm not sure why gforth doesn't have UWIDTH. It's actually really useful.

This solution also works in arbitrary bases.