# Am I an insignificant array?

Tags: code-golf, number, array, decision-problem

An *insignificant array* is an array of positive integers, where the absolute differences between consecutive elements are all smaller than or equal to **1**.

For example, the following array is insignificant:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4]
```

Because the corresponding (absolute) differences are:

```
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Which are all smaller than or equal to **1**.

---

Your task is to determine whether a given array of integers is insignificant.

- You may assume that the array always contains at least two elements.
- [Standard input and output rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) apply. You may take input (and output) in any reasonable format.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- The truthy / falsy values have to be distinct and consistent.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.

## Test cases

```
Input -> Output

[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4] -> true
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8] -> true
[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]          -> true
[3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4] -> true
[1, 2, 3, 4]                   -> true 
[5, 4, 3, 2]                   -> true 
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1]    -> false
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 19]   -> false
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5]       -> false
[1, 2, 4, 10, 18, 10, 100]     -> false
[10, 20, 30, 30, 30]           -> false
```

I used the values `true` and `false`.

Comment: Do the truthy/falsy values actually have to be truthy/falsy in our language of choice, or can we use any two distinct and consistent values?

Comment: @MartinEnder Any two distinct and consistent values. P.S Sorry for the late response

Comment: The text says you'll be given an array of integers, but that only arrays of positive integers can be insignificant. Should we be prepared for an array of negative integers?

Answer (score 26):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
IỊẠ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/z4e6uh7sW/P//P9pQR8FIR8FYR8EERprCkEksAA)**

## How?

Just the perfect challenge for Jelly.

```
IỊẠ   Full program.

I     Increments; Get the difference between consecutive elements.
 Ị    Insignificant; return abs(number) ≤ 1.
  Ạ   All; returns 1 if all the elements are truthy, 0 otherwise.
```

Comment: `P` wouldn't work would it, because if all the differences were `1` it'd output `1`, but if one of them was `0` it would output `0`? And if one difference was `5` but one was `0` it would still do `0`?

Comment: What about the "positive integers" requirement?

Answer (score 21):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>33</s> 29 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to @JohanKarlsson*

```js
a=>!a.some(v=>(a-(a=v))**2>1)
```

#### How?

When coerced to `Number`, arrays of at least two elements are evaluated to `NaN`. By re-using the input ***a*** as the variable holding the previous value, the first iteration of ***some()*** always results in ***([v0, v1, ...] - a[0]) ** 2 = NaN***, no matter the value of ***a[0]***. So, the first test is always falsy and the actual comparisons start at the 2nd iteration, just as they're meant to.

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

(a,p)=>!a.some(v=>(p-(p=v))**2>1)

console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4])) // true
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8])) // true
console.log(f([3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]         )) // true
console.log(f([3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4])) // true
console.log(f([1, 2, 3, 4]                  )) // true
console.log(f([5, 4, 3, 2]                  )) // true
console.log(f([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1]   )) // false
console.log(f([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 19]  )) // false
console.log(f([3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5]      )) // false
console.log(f([1, 2, 4, 10, 18, 10, 100]    )) // false
console.log(f([10, 20, 30, 30, 30]          )) // false
```

Comment: 29 bytes: `a=>!a.some(v=>(a-(a=v))**2>1)`

Comment: @JohanKarlsson Ah yes, the input is guaranteed to contain at least 2 elements, so that's safe. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It requires two value than t/f so `!` is unnecessary. Also even if 1 element possible `p-(p=v)` is zero and it works fine

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 40 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,*t:t==()or-2<n-t[0]<=1==f(*t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZHbCoMwDIav51MEdmNHBVt1U7FPIr1wbGWCq9J14J7edfUwD4OVPwmkH39I27z0rZZB1wlWFffzpQCJDzrVjLmoVh7NpKdzn2eMMCbcg0adqBW0UEpwHWeXEwwUQ4AhHHM0KuSA96DV87rizN0RwwlDjCExec4FFlqIw3QWXDhqQofO77kzm7UfGDAaregfkFgqsgskNke2Q/gAiqJ6DKN7rRYnCV@C21f5mPLv6JkjtSzxTcRD9X2@AU2fmgim4MtletBBKTSqlNo1X9si1L0B)

Answer (score 9):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```hs
all((<2).abs).(zipWith(-)=<<tail)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDNCoJAGLz7FINEGKzgrpYa2LFTt7rFFisqSmbhz6Gnt83afkyX@T6X2WFkJhXVKc7ztk0MsQyX5SxgK0OY4ezAptPEeDBagmNAV1Z7FlmBANEFGkwTVXpp8gi3LJZ7VzaxhmuZFTUmSLCnBIzAJnDUnis4fFQpXxcELoFH4Mv9q7Q72Q841OkrHYW3@MWM/f1jNeQ4V15sSNfU27rcFNB1DX/drEVe/ZVjd2HdLqbb3SVDOfq6J3oFUZ8PxP0u72HJgYGoUkgtOd7ra1m9QiTJ5Njv4e0d) *-1 byte thanks to [@user1472751](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/65900/user1472751)*

---

The point-free solution is <s>one</s> <s>two</s> again only one byte (*thanks to -1 byte from [@Dennis](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/12012/dennis)*) shorter than the recursive approach:

```hs
f(a:b:r)=2>(a-b)^2&&f(b:r)
f _=1>0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVDNCoJAGLz7FEOEGKzg@pMp6LFTt7rFEisqSabhz6Gnt81aK9Nlvs9ldhiZOfP6kuR516Ua9yO/WgVmyKNa43q0UtVUe1JKilNAQ6O78qxAgLiEAl1HfS7bPMY9S8Q@VG2i4FZlRYMlUhwpgUlgEdhyOxI2m1WK1zWBS7Ah8MT@VVq97AcM8oyVtsQgfjNzf/9YTTk60suc0rXNvql2BRYLBX/dbHle/5Vj9WHdPqbb3wVDGca6F0YFUY9NxP0u72nJgImoQkgNMZv31zBGhQjSFGMNw7oH)

Answer (score 9):

### Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
Max@Abs@Differences@#<2&
```

Comment: `#==Clip@#&@*Differences` is one byte shorter.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7PC4IwFMfv/RUPBE@L3NRUqDAIoUMQdBQPJtM86EF3CMS/fT3Xphl8396Pz7bva3Lx4k0u6iKXCRzlLX/H52cfX@qy5B1vC97H1oHZ8t7VrUivreAV7x4Cuyq1MtieIMGcgQ27eDMMlAAj4BLwzOkbeSOBFcfZnkBAICQQ4TlxV8GV9NgzmomerL@dOt/cY5q5yixQNoGqcUI1/OpvKxottr97Tq8XQ4TUwQh1dhzFsGQY7hzjKD8 "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online") and [23 bytes by Misha Larov](https://tinyurl.com/f65y8j4s)

Answer (score 8):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 21 bytes

```matlab
@(x)all(diff(x).^2<2)
```

Anonymous function that inputs a numeric vector and ouputs `1` if insignificant or `0` otherwise.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##dZFhC4MgEIa/9yvuY4FIaq1iC/Y/RoNoCYHUYDUGY7/d3SzbrCbvncf5qK/YVX15r7XMKaX66D@CUin/0kiJJT3zAw90016H/gY5POHECHACgkBkc2wVFR58h0Pi6o5AQiAlkGF2SWEwRysgspqZqfPvUrcf2718xQtjLzHGElNjh62wUYsXsWzL6O9rPyduWUSMhRjpNIfhgsImxxBzFPDae1WtlBxaXxIYfyXQbw)

Answer (score 7):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
._MI.+
```

**[Verify all the test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=._MI.%2B&input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+5%2C+5%2C+4%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+5%2C+5%2C+4%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+8%2C+9%2C+8%5D%0A%5B3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%5D%0A%5B3%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%0A%5B5%2C+4%2C+3%2C+2%5D%0A%5B1%2C+3%2C+5%2C+7%2C+9%2C+7%2C+5%2C+3%2C+1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+19%5D%0A%5B3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+8%2C+7%2C+5%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+4%2C+10%2C+18%2C+10%2C+100%5D%0A%5B10%2C+20%2C+30%2C+30%2C+30%5D&debug=0)**

---

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 8 bytes

```
.A<R2aVt
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/X8/RJsgoMazk//9oQx0FIx0FYx0FExhpCkMmsQA)

## Explanation

```
._MI.+   Full program.

    .+   Deltas.
   I     Is invariant under...
._M      Mapping with Sign. 0 if n == 0, -1 if n < 0, 1 if n > 0.
```

---

```
.A<R2aVt    Full program.

      Vt    Vectorize function, applied on the input zipped with the tail of the input.
     a      Absolute difference.
  <R2       For each, check if it is smaller than 2.
.A          All.
```

Comment: I have no idea why I thought `I#` instead of `M`.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 35 bytes

```python
x=input()
while-2<x.pop(0)-x[0]<2:1
```

Exists with status code **1** for insignificant arrays, with status code **0** otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDBboMwDIbPzVNYXQ@tlCISoC1btp1222HabUI5ZJCOSFVAJdXo0zOWFAqsWvTbkexPv@N8iipvUmHgCZSu1JdWe5UKbbzyDIyB19SPSpcns1yh71wd5Jqy2iuLcumv1nXic0bvSeMh14SjFNkDZAWalWeTF5reMmUwX7y/vL1@zNFMpnkBi2eUFVo2CcFAMQQYwi5HnUIOd2COJ4lGVNvZYNhi2GGI23ylAouMxKE/Ayrs1IOXyq2JA4uJF6Ak6mzovxixTGSfHdsc2QrhDtuLQ@WGOk2WJTEfYn//4deQ90OvbtSSxG9jd7l9n0@wtkrbCPrgoxUc9gM)

Answer (score 6):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
ΛεẊ-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zsc1sf7urS/f//f7ShjpGOsY4JGJuCoUksAA)

Explanation:

```
ΛεẊ- 2-function composition
Λ    (x -> y):f -> [x]:x -> TNum: Check if f returns a truthy result for all elements of x
 ε    f: TNum:x -> TNum: Check if abs(x) <= 1 (shamelessly stolen from Jelly)
  Ẋ   x: (x -> x -> y):f -> [x]:x -> [y]: reduce each overlapping pair of x by f
   -   f: TNum:x -> TNum:y -> TNum: y - x
```

Answer (score 6):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 6 bytes

```
äa e<2
```

[Try it online!](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=5GEgZTwy&input=WzEsIDIsIDMsIDQsIDMsIDQsIDUsIDUsIDUsIDRd)

### Explanation

```
ä        Get all pairs of elements
 a       Take absolute difference of each pair
         This results in the deltas of the array
   e     Check if every element...
    <2   Is less than 2
```

Answer (score 6):

## APL, 13 bytes

```
{×/(|2-/⍵)<2}
```

First APL answer \o/

Note: I am a bot owned by Hyper Neutrino. I exist mainly for chat testing.

## Explanation

```
{×/(|2-/⍵)<2}
{           }  Function; right argument is ⍵
   (     )     Bracketed Expression
       /       Reduce
     2         Every pair (two elements) of
        ⍵      ⍵
      -        Using subtraction
    |          Magnitude (Absolute Value)
          <2   For each element, is it less than two?
  /            Reduce over
 ×             Multiplication (Product) (All)
```

Comment: 11 bytes as tacit - `∧/2>(|2-/⊢)`

Comment: Vyxal bot how could you betray us like this? :p

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
¥Ä2‹P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//0NLDLUaPGnYG/P8fbaijYKSjYKyjYAIjTWHIJBYA)

**Explanation**

```
¥        # calculate deltas
 Ä       # absolute values
  2‹     # smaller than 2
    P    # product
```

Comment: @Okx: I'm afraid not. It won't work for `[5,2]` for example.

Comment: `2‹` can be `!` for -1 byte

Answer (score 5):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 25 bytes

```perl6
{?(2>all(.[]Z-.skip)>-2)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVHLTsMwELznK0aih1ZyKj/zUCH8B5UFPTQSIogqgQOq@u1hs46bpCCys2trPJnNOqdj22T9@zdWNR7Qnx/Xujo0zXq790/ptnt7PW2qVG8u/S65ezmfk70S0AJGwMbqIqxHWuGz/TouZXSUCeQChUBJdSYzrFnA4/rMZTbiqhyZP5vOTG7dkOxdNNL/6xSLHH97ydUxo/yoqw9NF/oG3IysSr/Q/b6OwdJPfSc/zVIlKYtxldLf6ojWlOaafjlH0F0uSXcY/vB69bxB/dHiXkHDwHI6DluJiXbIkKNAiWKgDWYRCMsRKN7PXh@2jk91YA0Z5mSW02qgAjnE1E2V0Tf2JnH0tDQ83QNXKZmVNDjNG1Dt@h8)

This should be pretty readable. The only less obvious thing here is that the zip operator `Z` will stop zipping when the shorter list is exhausted (we remove the first element of the list at the right) and that the empty subscript `.[]`, so called Zen slice, gives the whole list. `.skip` returns the list without the first element.

Comment: Are those two spaces really necessary?

Comment: @JonathanFrech: The right one probably no. Also I just realized that the `.rotate` is not needed here.

Comment: Heck, even the left one could be removed. I really don't understand where the whitespace is required and where it is not...

Comment: You could write `-2<` instead of `-1≤` and `<2` instead of `≤1` to save four more bytes.

Comment: Er, I guess you actually have to reverse the comparisons `2>...>-2` to avoid interpreting the `<` in an erroneous way.

Comment: @Sean, thanks. I missed the fact that the array will contain only positive integers.

Comment: I recently discovered the following trick: `.[]Z-.skip` saves 2 bytes.

Comment: @nwellnhof — wow! I mean: I was *searching* for a method that would do this, and didn't find it. (Apparently the docs need to get even better than they are now.) Many thanks!

Comment: While it doesn't change the length, you could use `so …` instead of `?(…)`

Comment: @BradGilbertb2gills: That would be probably nicer visually, but that's it. I just tend to use `?` everywhere because (I think) it's at worst the same length as `so`.

Answer (score 5):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 41 bytes

```
a=>all(-2<a[i]-a[i+1]<2for i:0..len(a)-1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NcRBCoAgEADAr@xxlzTS7BLWR8TDHgoEURH/v3URhmm9jlqk9VQGovB1c86oreeQov5bTPT2rR3Sua1rfgoyaUNCGIwCq2BX4ObH5CKRfA)

-16 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder
-2 bytes
-6 bytes thanks to Mr. Xcoder

Comment: [49 bytes (-16 bytes)](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@19QlJlXoqHxP9vWLjEnRyNa18gmOdogFoh0wbRhrI1RWn6RQrJVVWaBRrZOdrRhSX6sZqzmf02NaEMdBSMdBWMdBRMYaQpDJrGamv8B)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I think the space in `<2 for` might be omittable.

Comment: @JonathanFrech There is no space there?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder oh yeah I don't know what I was thinking with all those crazy function chainings. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 5):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>51</s> <s>45</s> 44 + 18 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to [Jeppe Stig Nielsen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8727/jeppe-stig-nielsen)*

```cs
a=>a.Zip(a.Skip(1),(x,y)=>x-y).All(x=>x*x<4)
```

Byte count also includes:

```cs
using System.Linq;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU9RT8IwEH5ef8XJA7SmNIxNgchIiIlPmhhHQqLxoY4ijaXDteiI4bdjuzEjmtz1Lt93993XzHSzvBAHzdfCbHgmIN0ZK9bsVup39IWCTHFjYIoC1wfGcisz@MjlAu641Jg40BPBzVZnY6nt0zOFlzxXE1hCcuDJhLNHucGcpW@uhITiku5IMim7O8KmSuHS9eflOCYHp3LlpYwtpH4FqTdbWwGfK6kExhUACVzn2uRKsAfBF86lwITAWQJ6qxS02/WeB1ot7y4Imvl5Ia2oFpa1Fks3SlrcoR0KHegQNl@JQuASkgmURwWWCiUyW4Puf@yeF8bNsFkh1@4yYbN8WhR853vvdo9c7A8hhT6FiELcvBdNxOg36YBLCgMKQwoj96KoYk4C1aNxoxY1y/GpGrpoJvoejSr1QaU7qHqHhJ6p44@HcIT@W/J7xwuOCXsuh8fa6yFf@y6jn/wG)

Explanation:

```cs
a =>                      // Take an array of integers as input
    a.Zip(                // Combine each element with corresponding one from:
        a.Skip(1),        //     the input array without first element
        (x, y) => x - y   //     get their difference
    )
    .All(x => x * x < 4)  // Check if all differences are less than 2
                          // (We only care about 0 and 1, and so happens that when they're squared, it works like Abs! Magic!)
```

Comment: Little improvement: `a=>a.Zip(a.Skip(1),(x,y)=>x-y).All(x=>x*x<4)`, it avoids the negation `!`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>30</s> 26 bytes

```r
cat(all(diff(scan())^2<2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZvs/rTQvuSQzP08jUTMxJ0cjJTMtDciMM7Ix0vyfppGsYaqjYKKjYKyjYKSpyQUSMAYLAIXNdBTMdRQswKSppqbCfwA)

Comment: I think `function(a)all(diff(a)^2<2)` saves 3 bytes.

Comment: you could take the input from the console: `all(diff(scan())^2<2)`

Comment: @BLT good point!

Comment: @flodel There was some [recent discussion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13743/how-should-a-full-program-in-r-be-invoked) regarding the need to explicitly  print the output when using `scan`, but it still saves a byte!

Answer (score 5):

## [Ohm v2](https://github.com/MiningPotatoes/Ohm), 4 bytes

```
Δ2<Å
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8/INfr//9wUI5vDrf//RxvqKBjpKBjrKJjoKJjqKJjpKJjrKFjoKFgCyVgA)

## How?

```
Δ2<Å   ~ Full program.

Δ      ~ Absolute deltas.
 2<    ~ Is smaller than 2?
   Å   ~ Check if all elements are truthy.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 62 bytes

```powershell
param($a)$l=$a[0];($a|?{$_-$l-in1..-1;$l=$_}).count-eq$a.count
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/vyCxKDFXQyVRUyXHViUx2iDWGsipsa9WiddVydHNzDPU09M1tAZJxtdq6iXnl@aV6KYWqiRCmP///3fQMNRRMNZRMNVRMNdRsASTpmARQ00A)

PowerShell doesn't have a `.map` or `.some` or similar command, so here we're individually checking each delta.

We take input `$a` and set `$l` equal to the first element. Then we loop through `$a` and take out each element where `|?{...}` the difference `$_-$l` is `-in` the range `1,0,-1`. We then set `$l` equal to the current element. So now we have a collection of elements where the delta between their previous neighbor is 1. We take the `.count` of that and check whether it's `-eq`ual to the `.count` of the array as a whole. If it is, then every delta is 1 or less, so it's an insignificant array. That Boolean result is left on the pipeline, and output is implicit.

Comment: You can save 1 byte by getting rid of the param and doing `$l=($a=$args)[0]`

Comment: @briantist That doesn't work, though. [For example.](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXHVkMl0VYlsSi9WDPaINYayKuxr1aJ11XJ0c3MM9TT0zW0BipSia/V1EvOL80r0U0tVEmEMP///@@gYaijYKSjYKyjYKIJAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")  This is because it's setting `$l` to be the whole input array in your suggestion.

Comment: I think it just requires changing the way you give arguments in TIO (each element needs to be specified separately). The way you have it now, the first element of `$args` is itself the whole array. [Example](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/XyXHVkMl0VYlsSi9WDPaINYayKuxr1aJ11XJ0c3MM9TT0zW0BipSia/V1EvOL80r0U0tVEmEMP///2/43@i/8X8TAA "PowerShell – Try It Online")

Comment: That feels cheaty...

Comment: I think that's actually the correct way to use `$args`. If you called a script or function with a series of arguments separated as spaces, it would come in as separate elements in `$args`, and for TIO that's how to emulate that. I've personally used it that way many times before, but to each their own :)

Answer (score 4):

## Factor, <s>48</s> 33 bytes

Saved 15 bytes thanks to @chunes!

```
[ dup rest v- vabs supremum 2 < ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY6xDsIwDET3fMX9QFsKdABVbGVlQEyIIYQgliqRnXSgCr8empIuyDrZOvvp/OZXVNLhgE9VPqVyhgpSaFt0p6O4nLs9rCTWBOmdKTxrkRYLwsaT0hlcKDFiRI01GuwQ8ryZVGM1KVVyG2xnNyDEKx7egjQ7DAUGeWewt6R7308XLW6xlxalmMMrY131i8zt/5P4BQ) (results are at the bottom)

`dup rest` makes a copy of the inputted sequence without the first element. `v-` subtracts that from the original sequence (\$a_n-a_{n-1}\$). Then `vabs` gets the absolute values of that. `supremum` finds the maximum value in the sequence, and `2 <` makes sure it's 0 or 1.

Comment: `vabs` is shorter than `[ abs ] map`. `supremum` is shorter than `0 [ max ] reduce`.

Comment: @chunes Nice, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 45 bytes

```python
lambda k:all(-2<x-y<2for x,y in zip(k,k[1:]))
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHbKjEnR0PXyKZCt9LGKC2/SKFCp1IhM0@hKrNAI1snO9rQKlZT839BUWZeiUaaRrShjoKRjoKxjoIJjDSFIROQQgA)** or **[Try the test suite.](https://tio.run/##XZDBDoMgDIbvPEWPmtREQOc0@iSOg8tiRmRqjAfdyztgoHPJXyj/B7TpuM7PoedbW9021bzujwa6olEqiFi5RGvJ2mGCBVeQPbzlGHTY1bQQYbgpqKCuKQJD4AiJX1OvRCA5ce1dEDKEK0KuV8O5hSc5O/HaiXPO35pT6u8xx7gtltkymc21Qx386q8rmh9lf/s0r4@CGtJYx9XtcWyZTpkOvocQhJjBSTM2VRAYJ9nPQRtIPbgP)**

Thanks to [Jonathan Frech](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/73111/jonathan-frech) for -2 bytes.

Comment: `abs(x-y)<2` -> `-2<x-y<2`.

Answer (score 3):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <del>6</del> 5 bytes

```
d|2<A
```

-1 byte thanks to *Giuseppe*

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P6XGyMbx//9oQx0FIx0FYx0FExhpCkMmsQA) or [Verify all test-cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D@lxsjG8b9LyP9oQx0FIx0FYx0FExhpCkMmsVwo0kAhMx0Fcx0FCx0FSyAJlDYGy6EgiKgJDMEloCIoZgI5pjBVRhAZY7A95mAbzMFsoIghRA6C0NxjaAm3EdmBIL1wu4ByhgZAbAGlDQxAUkCWERAbw3GsgoICAA)

Comment: I think [per meta consensus](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/95057/67312) you can use `d|2<` instead, as an array with a zero value is falsey in MATL.

Comment: Or `d|2<A` for something closer to your original answer.

Comment: @Giuseppe No they can't: *The truthy / falsy values have to be distinct and **consistent**.*

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder "an array of all 1s for truthy" and "an array containing at least one zero for falsey" isn't distinct and consistent?

Comment: @Giuseppe They are distinct, but inconsistent.

Comment: @Giuseppe I'll go for `d|2<A`, thanks!

Comment: @Giuseppe *"an array of all 1s for truthy" and "an array containing at least one zero for falsey" isn't distinct and consistent?* - No, that is not acceptable, because they are inconsistent.

Answer (score 3):

## C, <s>61</s> 56 bytes

*Thanks to @scottinet for saving five bytes!*

```
r;f(a,n)int*a;{for(r=1;--n;r=(*a-*++a)/2?0:r);return r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdPNboQgEADgu08x2aQJuJgC/peYPkjbg7Frs4fShtqT8dkt4GJ1MRhQA87nOGCXfHTdPCvRo5ZIfJVD3Iqx/1JINUwkiRSqQXGbxOdzix/5M31SWKjL8KskKDHNOgA@26tEOBoj0IcZGC4/A3t5gwZGRoATSAlk7py7lk3CRnwrHdOj08P7qzwR6JENJ8AoxiLaodxHNVQQKAlUBGp9DqH8EE0XNLXiroUsPV96VLZSmWurdhsJmdlhfvn9R4cIU1dPKBYhdwnxA2FjFM7YIeWaRmqrXtp6l/Zej7BQVuZZL6tqBZd2t6SsDonVkVhvy7/dGCbLkGY2jqcxui28XRvdq9uV0uD2pUfbg7mfQs9y3dO1e9a/pF@fG2ma/wA)

## C (gcc), 47 bytes

```
r;f(a,n)int*a;{for(r=1;--n;r=(*a-*++a)/2?0:r);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fdPNboQgEADgu08x2aQJ7GIK@F9i@iBtD8bWZg@1DfVmfHY74GJ1MRhAw8/nOGAbf7btPGvVkYb19NoP50aN3bcmuhYqjnula3Ju4vPl0tBH@cyfNFXTjPPgq7n2hEZjBHiZjuHjdxAvb1DDKBhIBgmD1LWZK@mk7IofjWs6cnp4f@1PDDpilzMQnFIV7VDpowjlDAoGJYMK2xAqD9FkQRMr7krIwvHCo9KVSl1ZtVtPyEwP48vuPzpEmLx6Qr4ImQtIHggbI3fGDinWMBKb9cLmu7DP2CNCUZm5XlTlCi7lbktFFRLLI7Hapn97MEyUIc0cHE8TfJt4uzdYy9ud8@Dx5UfHQ7ifAkcl1mStnvUv4eszI03zHw)

Comment: And if it is allowed / if you feel like it, you may save [9 more bytes](https://tio.run/##ldPNToQwEADgO08x2cSksCW2pfzZEB9EPRBczB5EU7kRnh2HsiCzatIlLZCh/TrplCZ@a5ppsqZlNe/Cc9dHtRnaD8tsJU0cd8ZWLKrj6Hisw3v1KB5saMYJx8F7fe5YGAwB4DUH@tNXL59eoIJBclAcEg56vadr06NxM1rmxnOQIlwinxaVlh3uXp@7AwdcKCC2@m2jl3HIORQcSrwTW91gJ4udOJg0QmIg9xT1Juq1beglQmh9Q7bp9U4Qad5kTyhboHRNTxEo@xv6oYiVb0klrjC5K0nu3jEiCT1/9Myx2NylXRVflgQu/OFyX6H9SZpzJuh8tDxRKfa1cUXFXlyeQtDTL/zPk1x/LZyjsCdbpyQunP5PjtM3 "C (gcc) – Try It Online") by storing the result in `r` instead of returning it. :-)

Comment: @scottinet I considered that, but it's not valid C even though it happens to work with gcc. It's allowed, though, so I guess I'll just include it as an alternate version.

Comment: I'm puzzled as to why using the global `r` to store the result and printing it in `main` is not valid C?

Comment: @scottinet Assigning a variable at the end of a function puts that value in the function's return adress, making it feel like it is returning the value. However, this behaviour is not part of the C specifications, thereby not guarenteed to work. It can also break with certain optimizing compiler flags.

Comment: Indeed, but that is not what I did in my proposal. I also modified the `main` function to make it print `r` (a global variable) explicitly instead of a returned value that do not exist anymore. That's why I wondered if that was allowed by rules.

Comment: @scottinet Ah, I am sorry. I think that would not be allowed as you cannot simply assign variables in your solution per agreed upon rule. As an example, using globally defined variables instead of function arguments would not be allowed either. Your task is to write a fully functional program / function.

Comment: I am not sure, but is [this](https://tio.run/##jdPNaoQwEADg@z7FdKGQxCzmx1/EJ2l7kG0te6gtqTfx2e1sXK1uhxKZRB3Mx@Ak59P7@TxNrmrZpetFw4f20zFX60qwJtK8cqJ@YEw0JxFFDY8N59U44afw0Vw6xg/DAfC6Jvq3714/vUANg5ZgJFgJyTKnSySxELFUY@XXtcyv4vPbl0OnZcfH1@fuKMFheqebvzqKmYRcQiGhxJnQTaBuZ916ehcEagPRZEWTJVb3liH0JFBP738IYaWBVjZb6VKjIayMsH61HZevpVnfpdz3J/fPmNGEngdWWqz0HHebQZeEXQTa5bZf2811rZxwy0BXq22r0NYKR3G7K0WdChVqL6cOKYPDroNS/zls4/QD) valid?

Comment: @JonathanFrech languages are defined by their implementation here, so if you have a compiler which produces consistent results then the answer is valid, even if formally UB.

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 60 bytes

```java
a->{int r=1,p=a[0];for(int i:a)r|=(r=p-(p=i))*r;return r<2;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVJtb4IwEP7ur7iYmMBSkBfZVMRkP2DJkn00fqgIpg4LaYuJcfx2VlogKmYZubvS63PPXZvniM/YyouEHvffdVHuMhJDnGHO4QMTCtcRQJvlAgu5nHOyh5M8M74EI/Sw2QJmB242SICjpLNLQTI7LWksSE7tT5bsSYxFsiJUbLZrSCGCGlvrq9wDi1xURHjjbMM0Z0aTIktssp/IYFFhGUVETPOFhSwRJaPAVl5Y1aHqpehke5FwwSWnngDg6iLwEPgIZl0MOptVCKZTEKxMnqEl4hXBG4I5goWMQ7SvoHcmQf03RM866wvazF@T3FI@ckMHDzpa719wV2EDdb2FioHKuLpawlOc8dthtD08jrtQ@Ef48P2aBv1gT9g9VeE60uft6jhtwQAuTz3pfu93V76DV1odUk1gKIkogSy1TMxeJV8XLpKTnZfCLqSORWqMJ5bv8SVMdhM6RjdSfmcMX7gtcq14o2EyEaR286N3pm5ajRqv6l8)

- 5 bytes thanks to @Nevay!

Comment: You can use `r` in the loop to calculate `(p-n)` only once, `>>1` can be `/2`, or removed if you use `|` instead of `+`: `a->{int r=1,p=a[0];for(int i:a)r|=(r=p-(p=i))*r;return r<2;}` (60 bytes).

Comment: Cheers @Nevay, thank you! Perfect golfing, as usual ;-)

Comment: can you explain me how does it work? thank you!

Answer (score 3):

## [anyfix](https://github.com/alexander-liao/anyfix), 9 bytes

```
I€A€2<»/&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8yrTMus@P/f81HTGkcgNrI5tFtf7f///9GGOgpGOgrGOgomMNIUhkxiAQ)

```
I€A€2<»/&  Main Link
I          Deltas
 €         For each element
  A        Take its absolute value
   €  »    For each element
    2<     Is it less than two?
       /   Reduce over
        &  Logical AND
```

This is mostly a port of the 05AB1E solution except terrible because anyfix doesn't have autovectorization and other cool things

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <strike>36</strike> <strike>35</strike> 33 bytes

```ruby
->b,*a{a.all?{|x|(b-(b=x))**2<2}}
```

Takes the input array as individual arguments.

-1 byte thanks to MegaTom, -2 bytes thanks to Jordan.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y5JRyuxOlEvMSfHvrqmokYjSVcjybZCU1NLy8jGqLb2f0FpSbFCWrShjoKRjoKxjoIJjDSFIZNYLiyKgBJmOgrmOgoWOgqWQBKuyBisAgUhy5nAEFwaKoLFFriQKUyHEbIqY7ArzMH2m4PZQBFDZBUQhOZmQ0s09yB7BWQOmkuAKgwNgNgCShsYIBQA@UZAbAzHsf8B)

Comment: `->a{b,=a;a.all?{|x|(b-(b=x))**2<2}}` is 35 bytes.

Comment: @MegaTom right you are!

Comment: `->b,*a{a.all?{|x|(b-(b=x))**2<2}}` is 33 bytes.

Comment: @Jordan Not sure if that works - how are you passing the array into it? Passing the array like in the TIO just gives true for all test cases.

Comment: No array, just pass the input as individual arguments.

Comment: @Jordan nice, didn't know about that one. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 21 bytes

```julia
~x=all(diff(x).^2.<2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFha8MgEIa/51cc/aQgJZqka8YcDPYvwg3CkhQXyUq00H3pX8@sM1lcy@S9E86H9zz9OGlV76bpcpa11qRRXUfOdPsmtk@CTo18Ve@WJBVnIBhkDPI5F7NyBPkMdjy1LObc2Y7BA4M9g9LlNZd5KBLCsiIun7WgoXK/78rmjl8xO4n/Oe6hwl@/9LnwFY6B62ptAvijP2PzEmPw9k2upvjbeeUoPMtTF/uwpynegK4uXGRLYDxLAGmSHEc1WD2QzYvWYFtjDRxrY9RweIQNg@vPV5cepISm6hG6zxF6UAP07ZchDUVKp28)

-1 byte thanks to MarcMush: pass a single argument to `all`

Comment: you can add the missing functionnality yourself to mimic later behaviour (`import Base: <; <(x) = i->i<x`)

Comment: -1 byte (and works in julia 1.0) `~x=all(diff(x).^2 .<2)`

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 78 bytes

```java
a->{int p=0,i=1;for(;i<a.length;p+=Math.abs(a[i]-a[i++-1])>1?1:0);return p<1;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc7NboMwEATgV9kjFGPF/ZNaA5Fy6K2nnCrEYUtMYgpryyypIsSzU6utNJrDN5fp8Yq584b609dmR@8CQx9NzmwH2c3UsnUk77QlNqHD1sDH8vbPRcS6EXBwbjBIFQQoYcO8WuIAvtwJWyrduZBoW6AcDJ35on1WviNfJH5OCda2yWNlWa6atFJ79bpLdTA8BwJfKL1uemJk28LV2ROMaCk5crB0rhtMl@NtYjNKN7P0EXmgJEj0frglZL7h99@iBPzlXsCDgEcBTwKeo7ysaarXdfsB)

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>37</s> 36 bytes

```
(a,u)=>!a.some(e=>(e-=(u=e))>1|e<-1)
```

Edit: Saved 1 byte by stealing @Arnauld's trick.

Comment: You could use currying: `a=>u=>!a.some(e=>(e-=(u=e))>1|e<-1)`

Comment: @Bálint Sorry for the late response; I don't normally comment on "use currying" comments, but I will here because I'm not sure that's legal here since `u` is a temporary, not a parameter. (I can't use a global as it needs to start out as `undefined` and a global would not be reusable.) I guess I could apply the golf that was since applied to his answer of using `a` instead of `u` though...

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth, 7 bytes

```
._I#I.+
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=._I%23I.%2B&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+5%2C+5%2C+4%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+8%2C+9%2C+8%5D%0A%5B3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%5D%0A%5B3%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%0A%5B5%2C+4%2C+3%2C+2%5D%0A%5B1%2C+3%2C+5%2C+7%2C+9%2C+7%2C+5%2C+3%2C+1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+19%5D%0A%5B3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+8%2C+7%2C+5%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+4%2C+10%2C+18%2C+10%2C+100%5D%0A%5B10%2C+20%2C+30%2C+30%2C+30%5D&debug=0)

Returns true/false.

Explanation:

```
     .+ Deltas, returns differences between consecutive values.
._      Signum, returns the sign of a number (1, 0, or -1).  Note that this should
             be equal to the input for insignificant arrays.
  I     Tests if it is equal to the input...
   #    For each in the input, and filter out those that aren't...
    I   And make sure none have been filtered out.
```

Answer (score 2):

### Mathematica, 34 bytes

```
Differences@#~MatchQ~{(1|0|-1)..}&
```

## Explanation

```
                                 & (* Function *)
Differences                        (* which takes the consecutive differences*)
           @#                      (* of the input list *)
             ~MatchQ~              (* and returns whether it matches *)
                     {(1|0|-1)..}  (* a list consisting of one or more 1s, 0s, or -1s *)
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7JCoMwEIbvfYoBQVqI1rhUPbR4KEIPhZYexYNIXA56sLm5vLod06i18E9m@ZL8UyW8YFXCyzQZQziP1zLLWMPqlL0DZbgnPC2eQ7unndFp9KDrvTo@mrLm0a3mLGfNi2OXR0oM2gVCzDGocAx2bUsJmAQsAvZ8OrPsnsCG4@xEwCXgEfDxnLgl4EZybM9aiJxsv506Z75nSmYJM1fYuKLGCZXwq7@tqL/a/u45vV4NEVIDw5PZMATD0sSwluj78QM "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### TI-Basic, <s>6</s> 7 bytes

```
prod(2>abs(ΔList(Ans
```

or, 5 bytes if errors count as valid return value (returns `ERR:ARGUMENT` if insignificant, else `ERR:DOMAIN`)

```
augment(sin⁻¹(ΔList(Ans
```

Comment: This should probably have `abs(ΔList(Ans`, or else drops by more than 1 (such as in {5,3,1} or in the test case {3,4,5,6,7,8,7,5}) don't get detected.

Comment: @MishaLavrov thanks, you're right!

Answer (score 2):

## Swift 4, 52 bytes

```swift
{!zip($0.dropFirst(),$0).map(-).contains{1<abs($0)}}
```

Test suite:

````swift
let isInsignificant: (_ array: [Int]) -> Bool = {!zip($0.dropFirst(),$0).map(-).contains{1<abs($0)}}

let testcases: [(input: [Int], expected: Bool)] = [
    (input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4], expected:  true),
    (input: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 8], expected:  true),
    (input: [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],          expected:  true),
    (input: [3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], expected:  true),
    (input: [1, 2, 3, 4],                   expected:  true),
    (input: [5, 4, 3, 2],                   expected:  true),
    (input: [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 7, 5, 3, 1],    expected: false),
    (input: [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 19],   expected: false),
    (input: [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 5],       expected: false),
    (input: [1, 2, 4, 10, 18, 10, 100],     expected: false),
    (input: [10, 20, 30, 30, 30],           expected: false),
]

for (caseNumber, testcase) in testcases.enumerated() {
    let actual = isInsignificant(testcase.input)
    assert(actual == testcase.expected,
        "Testcase #\(caseNumber) \(testcase.input) failed. Got \(actual), but expected \(testcase.expected)!")
    print("Testcase #\(caseNumber) passed!")
}
```
````

Answer (score 2):

### Clojure, 35 bytes

```
#(every? #{-1 0 1}(map -(rest %)%))
```

How neat is that?

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZDbCsIwDIbvfYrAGLTQQQ@b2658EPFCtAVlzlGnIOKz11jXoe4Af9KSfkn/dledj1erHdlrA8ZFRN@0va8geiQCOIgnOW0bSIjVlxZiGlPq6II09lC3VQ3EwFowkAwUgzTkLCjd0BkYgSWDnEHBoMQ8gJUnfzTGpEE91lVmbh8cZWGCHOtS3m3ufeZ@jxUxRn7090ZRTvj@/oL33AnHSAqOUXQr50MQ6xJD9YGIewE "Clojure – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://www.jsoftware.com/), <strike>20</strike> 19 bytes

```
i=.[:*/2>[:|2&(-/\)
```

I defined it as a verb, which adds 3 bytes to the total length.

### Explanation

```
2&(-/\) finds the difference between two consecutive elements
| takes the absolute value
[: caps the fork so that the result is propagated onwards
2> finds if the values are smaller than 2
*/ calculates the product of all the elements, so yields 1 only if all are 1s
[: caps the fork so that the result is propagated onwards
```

### Example:

```
   i 1 3 5 7 9 7 5 3 1  
0
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##VY5HDsIwEEX3c4q/QoBE4hZSpHCRsEmvEhfg7sZFIxGPy/Ofsf9s1q510lT3JFWvpvqqy/WRvm@2RZ1AQkHDhJWFMNT9JzI8kaNAiYJ6n9CnAGiIqgkR1cA0/v/jB01eyUKZisoca7RTc@eRu1O7Oy1Rl6c@ZAna2I0b809AO3sZSAFZhF0I0BESAkpA83T1Y798sKJl6Bh6hoFhZJgYZoaFYWPYGQ5rfw)

Comment: `[:*/2>2|@-/\]` should work for 6? fewer bytes.

Comment: @cole Thanks, this is much better than mine!

Comment: `[:*/2>&|2-/\]` for 13: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY67DsIwDEV3f8UVAxUISl6lpVJZkJiYWIGhLYU@kPgB/j3kIUsQx8nxtRN7tLM0GVCVSLCCQOl8neJwPh3tpVxu1H7@UevN9WYXVKNKIaGgYYJnwQw1v4kMW@QosENBrU/oPwPoHlUTLKqBqfv9xy96eCULZSoqz1ijnZq7Hrm7tYupj7r8m0PuQCN348H8E9DEvQykgCzCKQToFRICSkDzdvVd278xoGZoGFqGO0PH8GB4MvQMI8PE8LL2Cw "J – Try It Online") EDIT: woops I see cole beat me to it.  I'll leave this here for the TIO.

Answer (score 2):

### F#, 56 bytes

```
let f a=Seq.forall(fun(x,y)->abs(x-y)<2)(Seq.pairwise a)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

-2 bytes from @ngn's improvements

```
&/2>#'!'1_-':
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY3BDoQgDETv@xWz2UROZlsKC3rwR4zxpgcT///GQpFoBkrzWmaO/tzPlLax@9rpY96G196MaZsZFgKn16vc8rqxxw8BEQNiwYKHKnCqirR/fC@t16mtVLJhyGYhvwKusOhO46H5tuy83DwdmMBRK5FSgiXIdZb0Bw)

- `-':` subtract each value in the (implicit) input from its predecessor
- `1_` drop the first result
- `#'!'` take the absolute value (literally, take the count of the range of each value; e.g. `1` -> `,0`, `-2` -> `-2 -1`)
- `&/2>` are all the absolute values smaller than 2?

Comment: here's an idea: `abs:{#'!'x}`

Comment: Makes the literal translation a bit more... nuanced, but saves some bytes! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 17 bytes

```
!x=diff(x)⊆-1:1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=fZFLCsIwEIZx21OMrqqM0PShrVAvIlkIGoiWKLUVT-DCK7jpxgN4Ce-gS09iTNPaaDHMAyZf_skk58sqT_i8eHRuXGzzLJ5ZM4LgIngIfhWDynwK8RSyNF-iycm9EcIYIUSIZGxynoIMo1Avg_Mrq1Fdae_bkGnRCyol9z9HFBSo60cqBqpCqObYPNlpsLSvsUlETfD3Td6i9NO5oegqljjSQ50dh_6Asu5K92qn5iwapJc8Y8Pw2j3EC86Yfeg_T8chmZCyfh-wTQr2Gvd94ALUl1sA25SLLBF2d4096MlNaykW5YmiKPML)

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 8 [bytes](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265917/97916)

```
≅±.≡/-◫2
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAg4omFwrEu4omhLy3il6syCgpmIFsxIDIgMyA0IDMgNCA1IDUgNSA0XSAjIC0-IHRydWUKZiBbMSAyIDMgNCA1IDYgNyA4IDkgOF0gIyAtPiB0cnVlCmYgWzMgMyAzIDMgMyAzIDNdICAgICAgICMgLT4gdHJ1ZQpmIFszIDQgNCA0IDMgMyAzIDQgNCA0XSAjIC0-IHRydWUKZiBbMSAyIDMgNF0gICAgICAgICAgICAgIyAtPiB0cnVlIApmIFs1IDQgMyAyXSAgICAgICAgICAgICAjIC0-IHRydWUgCmYgWzEgMyA1IDcgOSA3IDUgMyAxXSAgICMgLT4gZmFsc2UKZiBbMSAxIDEgMiAzIDQgNSA2IDE5XSAgIyAtPiBmYWxzZQpmIFszIDQgNSA2IDcgOCA3IDVdICAgICAjIC0-IGZhbHNlCmYgWzEgMiA0IDEwIDE4IDEwIDEwMF0gICMgLT4gZmFsc2UKZiBbMTAgMjAgMzAgMzAgMzBdICAgICAgIyAtPiBmYWxzZQ==)

```
≅±.≡/-◫2
      ◫2  # windows of length two
   ≡/-    # subtract second column from first (differences)
  .       # duplicate
 ±        # sign (pervasive across array)
≅         # do they match?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 38 + 2 (-ap) = 40 bytes

```perl
$_&&=abs$i-$F[-1]<2while($i=pop@F)&&@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18lXk3NNjGpWCVTV8UtWtcw1saoPCMzJ1VDJdO2IL/AwU1TTc3B7f9/MwVzBQsFy3/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6yYWAAA)

Comment: I don't think `-p` is needed to be a +1. Does it?

Answer (score 1):

## [RProgN 2](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/RProgN-2), 8 bytes

```
{-â2<}á*
```

### Explained

```
{-â2<}á*
{    }á     # Fold the input by the function
 -          # Subtract, get the difference.
  â         # Absolute
   2<       # Is less than 2.
       *    # Get the product, 1 for truthy, 0 for falsey.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kyooyk/P0zX6r2Goo2Cko2Cso2ACI01hyETzf7Xu4UVGNrWHF2r9/w8A)

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 53 bytes

```
(lambda(a)(every(lambda(x y)(< -2(- x y)2))a(cdr a)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYgxDoAgEAS/sp17BYWInZ85wYIEDcHEyOtRTMw0M@NTPHNjLvHwYGPSfQ1KFW7XVurfN6pwgbE06G5FlD4UqIi0gSMsJriX@cP1/QA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), <s>42</s> 41 bytes

```
all(keys[1:][]as$i|.[$i]-.[$i-1]|.*.;.<2)
```

Explained

```
all(                   # true if all values from
    keys[1:][] as $i   # scanning input indices starting at second element
  | .[$i]-.[$i-1]      # calculate differences between successive elements
  | .*.                # square the difference
; . < 2                # are < 2
)
```

Sample Run

```
$ jq -Mc 'all(keys[1:][]as$i|.[$i]-.[$i-1]|.*.;.<2)' data.json
true
true
true
true
true
true
false
false
false
false
false

$ echo -n 'all(keys[1:][]as$i|.[$i]-.[$i-1]|.*.;.<2)' | wc -c
  41
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 55 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from range `[1:1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window

```vba
[2:2]="=IfError(If(B1=0,0,ABS(B1-A1)),0)":?[Max(2:2)>1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 13 bytes

```
$2d-|v.;Og2<#
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/1/FKEW3pkzP2j/dyEb5////0YY6CsY6CqY6CuY6CpZg0hQsYhgLAA)

```
                 \ Implicit: Input on stack
$      ;         \ While there are items left on stack:
 2d-|            \   Get the absolute difference of the last two integers
     v           \   Send this to the second stack
      .          \   Pop the last item 

        O        \ Go to the second stack (list of differences)
         g       \ Sort ascendingly (largest item last)
          2<#    \ Check if it is smaller than 2 (print 1/0 accordingly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 85 bytes

```
function a($p){$r=1;foreach($p as$k=>$q)if($p[$k+1]&&abs($p[$k+1]-$q)>1)$r=0;echo$r;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZLNDoIwDIDvPkVjFgJxJowfgUzxQZDDJBCMCUzQk/HVxTKBiKIXk7Zb229tt0zmsllvJdrsUiTnQ1mA0Ik0rqTaMJ6VVSqSHAMganLchORkHDJ0I3JcsFjTxL4evCUmQ2bgQZOnSV6Sit8aoUeMgkXBpuD01u3FiQ0OLQvzXTHnszcaiRUFj4JPIUD7SdsKHckk5PQycF3k1wCfObevYX3r8joyWneyvq04T13KU3uMsEn0KW8vwoK/2lsKZSaq362mOUFiwkK1Bx0zzb2U7Yepm2XxAA)

It can probably be golfed some more, but it's a start.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZLNDoIwDIDvPkVjFgJxJowfgUzxQZDDJBCMCUzQk/HVxTKBiKIXk7Zb229tt0zmsllvJdrsUiTnQ1mA0Ik0rqTaMJ6VVSqSHAMganLchORkHDJ0I3JcsFjTxL4evCUmQ2bgQZOnSV6Sit8aoUeMgkXBpuD01u3FiQ0OLQvzXTHnszcaiRUFj4JPIUD7SdsKHckk5PQycF3k1wCfObevYX3r8joyWneyvq04T13KU3uMsEn0KW8vwoK/2lsKZSaq362mOUFiwkK1Bx0zzb2U7Yepm2XxAA "PHP – Try It Online") (link in answer is broken)

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 16 bytes

```
L,vbUÑ_€|2ª>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99Hpywp9PDE@EdNa2qMDq2y@///f7ShjoKRjoKxjoIJjDSFIZNYAA)

### How it works

```
L,		; Create a lambda function
		; Example argument: 	    ['[1 2 3 4 3 4 5 5 5 4]']
	vbU	; Evaluate as list; STACK = [1 2 3 4 3 4 5 5 5 4]
	Ñ_	; Deltas;	    STACK = [1 1 1 -1 1 1 0 0 -1]
	€|	; Absolute values;  STACK = [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1]
	2ª>	; All less than 2;  STACK = [1]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Regex (ECMAScript), 27 bytes

```
^(x(x*)(,(?=\2x?x?\b)|$))*$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZBNc9owEIbv/AqRyYy0IIzNRxpQBKcecsmhPRJ3RgHZUaMYjyyom8BvJ7JqPptpPSvJs3r2Xb37U6xFMTcqt50iVwtpXpfZi/y9MzyTv9A3mX4tc0Le@KTb2v0gJSlbQCiZ8sdeOS2nj0@wuQZoXe9a3TcI7PK7NSpLCQSFVnNJbmhnAMDW/Oo@WwutFkhl@cqOr1iyNCThESOaGykWWmWSADR5ttKaJTyEd5WQZgK507MEWCPlOjAy18LJdlG7MwlaXYoxMMelszBucjzDm01ad@5ETgzHGN5dv8IasgZW/2lg82VmVbaSbJvyfUVEXQ1rODnik7lWlmCKAQIts9Q@30X/E2tUrhQPackxZuourSuZare9IVU8iAcieC5MIe@dsXSmYoDPdb3Ik5vOC9tWtVC2uXsPq44SV8OQwhIBrq@7Lp3do9syeBV2/kwMcD/SKU6ELuQY4TG2ZuV@ED7ttd3uZhFFPYr6FA32@3Afgxh1JqgqbJxh7uqGoi8U3VI0cvsJ1vfMWcTo8J1ig30cyDrzadMTkUs11JgN90K9f3ORh4b@7SO/D30mimvOj8tzf@LCcjSKz7i/x1FJxse@R72eR6PQrdv6DMP4knPpnlv9w4rPfXjuAw)

Input is a list of positive unary numbers separated by `,`. Each one is a string of `x`s whose length represents the number.

```
^
(
    x(x*)         # \2 = this element - 1
    # Assert that either the next element is in the range \2 to \2+2 inclusive,
    # or that we've reached the end and there are no more elements.
    (
        ,         # Skip to the next element
        (?=       # look ahead to the next element to make the following assertion:
            \2    # subtract \2 from it
            x?x?  # subtract any number from 0 to 2 from it
            \b    # assert that we matched the exact number
        )
    |
        $
    )
)*
$
```

## Regex (ECMAScript), 21 bytes

```
\b(x+)(xx+,|,xx+)\1\b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZDLdtsgEIb3fgqSDYyFZcmXNDbBXXWRTRbt0tYC20ihIbIOwq6a2M/uICpfm9NyhoEzfPMPMz/FRpQLowrbKQu1lOZ1lb/I33vDc/kLfZfZt6og5I1Puu39bE6qAEhVBXRLnYdZPJvv2903CO3qhzUqzwiEpVYLSe5oZwDANvz2Md8IrZZI5cXajm9ZujIk5TEjmhspllrlkgDc8HytNUt5BO8qJTcpFE7PEmCtjOvQyEILJ9tFQWcStrsUY2COy6ZRcsPxFG@3WVO5EzsxnGB4d/VKa8gGWHPTwBar3Kp8Ldku44eMmLoc1nJyxAcLrSzBFAOEWuaZfX6I/yfWqrtSPKIVx5iph6zJZCoIfEOqfBJPRPBCmFI@usayqUoAPtf1InM3nRe2q3OhCrj7D6uPCtfDkMISAa6ue65cu6duq/BV2MUzMcD9SL9ia9ZyjBAe41To0l3xea3dbj@NKepR1KdocPDDgw0S1JmgWqJ1gbmnO4q@UHRP0cj5M6zvmQtL0HGdY4ODHckm8mnRM5FrNdSaDg9CvX9zsYeG/u8j74c@EicN54fkuT921XI8Si64v8dRSyanuie9nkfjyO375oyi5Jpz4Z7b/eNOLvvw3Ac)

Returns a non-match if the array is insignificant, and a match otherwise (i.e., its boolean result is inverted).

If this solution were converted to match=true logic, it would be `^(?!.*\b(x+)(xx+,|,xx+)\1\b)` **(28 bytes)**.

```
           # No anchor; can match starting anywhere
\b         # Assert word boundary, i.e. either the start of the string before
           # an "x", a position after an "x" and before a ",", a position
           # after a "," and before an "x", or the end of the string after an
           # "x".
(x+)       # \1 = any substring of "x"es
(
    xx+,   # 2 or more "x"es followed by ","
|          # or
    ,xx+   # "," followed by 2 or more "x"es
)
\1         # Match what was captured in \1
\b         # Assert word boundary
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator), 46 bytes

```
\left\{max(abs(n[2,...,n.length]-n))<2\right\}
```

[View on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6tihvg58t8)

This is a rare case where I think using `\left\{\right\}` is more efficient than not.

Comment: A few golfs: [31 bytes](https://mothereff.in/byte-counter#%0Af%28l%29%3D%5C%7B%5Cmax%28%28l%5B2...%5D-l%29%5E2%29%3C2%5C%7D). [Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/klvp0azbld). [Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3prvnsrgm5)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
¯vṅA
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwiwq924bmFQSIsIiIsIlsxLDIsMyw0LDUsNiw3LDgsOSw4XVxuWzEwLDIwXSJd)

```
¯vṅA
¯    # delta (consecutive diff)
 vṅ  # abs(a) ≤ 1
   A # all truthy?
```

-1 thx to @Sʨɠɠan

Comment: `ȧ1≤` is just `ṅ`, or in this case, `vṅ`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
._MI.+
```

[Test suite](https://pythtemp.herokuapp.com/?code=._MI.%2B&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+5%2C+5%2C+4%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+8%2C+9%2C+8%5D%0A%5B3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%5D%0A%5B3%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%2C+3%2C+3%2C+3%2C+4%2C+4%2C+4%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%5D%0A%5B5%2C+4%2C+3%2C+2%5D%0A%5B1%2C+3%2C+5%2C+7%2C+9%2C+7%2C+5%2C+3%2C+1%5D%0A%5B1%2C+1%2C+1%2C+2%2C+3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+19%5D%0A%5B3%2C+4%2C+5%2C+6%2C+7%2C+8%2C+7%2C+5%5D%0A%5B1%2C+2%2C+4%2C+10%2C+18%2C+10%2C+100%5D%0A%5B10%2C+20%2C+30%2C+30%2C+30%5D&debug=0)

###### Explanation:

```
._MI.+  | Full code
._MI.+Q | with implicit variables
--------+------------------------------------
    .+Q | Differences of the input
   I    | Is it invariant over:
._M     |  Replace each element with its sign
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rust](https://www.rust-lang.org/), 43 bytes

```rust
|a|a.windows(2).all(|s|(s[1]-s[0]).abs()<2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxBCsIwEEX3PcW4kRlIi40VilUvErJIsYFATKAT6cJ49hiEPj5v8RdvfXMqNsDLuIAEnwYqfklgr2ADHpUbNbWPOUYPdyjZZNNtLjzjxiipM95j5oyset2yOul6zYx0k1Smf6sxzMuaDmhrrBcgBZwFDLsv@wZNNDXf8gM)

A `fn(&[i8])->bool`.

Comment: Hmm, could you point me to meta consensus on an external type annotation being allowed?

Comment: @Maya https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25156/should-rust-anonymous-functions-fully-specify-parameter-types

Comment: @chunes That seems to be about the case when the examples themselves disambiguate it.

Comment: @Maya We have a clear answer on that about Java and C#, which IMO applies just as well to Rust https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11223.

Comment: @Maya But you're right that for the purpose of documentation, it's better to put the type in the answer.

Comment: @corvus_192 ah, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 5 bytes

```
₋Å2<Π
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UVP34VYjm3ML/v@PttQx07GMBQA)

```
₋           implicit input; get differences
 Å          Åbsolute value
  2<        is each difference less than 2?
    Π       product; implicit print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 11 bytes

```
2>M:BAD_MPg
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgwYKlpSVpuharjex8rZwcXeJ9A9IhIlCJfdGGOgpGOgrGOgomMNIUhkxioaoA)

#### Explanation

```lisp
2>M:BAD_MPg
          g  ; List of command-line arguments
        MP   ; Map to each pair of adjacent elements:
     AD      ;  Absolute difference between
    B        ;  the second and
       _     ;  the first
  M:         ; Get the max of that list
2>           ; 1 (truthy) if the max is less than 2; 0 (falsey) otherwise
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 7 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 5.76 bytes

```
z[ZA2<P
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLq6KjHI1sAiA8qOCCfdGGOgpGOgrGOgomMNIUhkxiIaoA)

Outputs `0` for False and `1` for True.

##### Explanation

```python
z[ZA2<P  # Implicit input
z[       # Differences of the input
  ZA     # Absolute value of each
    2<P  # Are they all less than 2?
         # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel, <s>35</s> 33 bytes

```
=AND(ABS(DROP(ζ,1)-DROP(ζ,-1))<2)
```

*2 bytes saved under the assumption that the input can be arbitrarily chosen so as to be a vertical vector.*

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 4 bytes

```
∆A2<
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FssedbQ5GtksKU5KLoYKLbjFyBdtqKNgpKNgrKNgAiNNYcgklgtFGihkpqNgrqNgoaNgCSSB0sZgORQEETWBIbgEVATFTCDHFKbKCCJjDLbHHGyDOZgNFDGEyEEQmnsMLeE2IjsQpBduF1DO0ACILaC0gQFICsgyAmJjOI6FhAsA)

```
∆A2<
∆       Differences
 A      Absolute value
  2<    Is less than 2?
```

---

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-e`, 4 bytes

```
∆:±=
```

A port of [@Mr. Xcoder's Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/143290/9288).

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJuqlLsgqWlJWm6FssfdbRZHdpou6Q4KbkYKrbgFiNftKGOgpGOgrGOggmMNIUhk1guFGmgkJmOgrmOgoWOgiWQBEobg-VQEETUBIbgElARFDOBHFOYKiOIjDHYHnOwDeZgNlDEECIHQWjuMbSE24jsQJBeuF1AOUMDILaA0gYGICkgywiIjeE4FhIuAA)

```
∆:±=
∆       Differences
 :      Duplicate
  ±     Sign
   =    Equal?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 57 bytes

```lua
for i=2,#arg do b=b or 1<(arg[i]-arg[i-1])^2 end print(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P8/Lb9IIdPWSEc5sShdISVfIck2SQEoZGijARSIzozVBVO6hrGacUYKqXkpCgVFmXklGkma////N/xv9N/4vwkYm4KhCQA)

Outputs `false` if the array is insignificant, or `true` if it is not.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 54 bytes

2 bytes thanks to Jonathan Frech.

```python
lambda a:all(-2<a[i]-a[i+1]<2for i in range(len(a)-1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dY/RDoIgFIbve4pzCQs3AU1t9iTmBa0sN0LnvOnp6UTigtn2nwP7zwf8jK/5MRhpu9PZavW8XBWoo9KaJKJWTd8m2Pa8rUU3TNBDb2BS5n4j@maIogmn1I5Tb2bSkYYzEAwkg8z33CtrKd1tgjg8MCgYlAwq7AEoHRUonmdeK7I4f14M7NyfFDEtXbLCZSrcHh0eU19Ff@HVRsbfb37u20iHFE@xymVN0xBCT2DJtXBs3w)

Comment: `abs(a[i]-a[i+1])<2` -> `-2<a[i]-a[-~i]<2`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 36 bytes

```clj
#(every? #{-1 0 1}(map - %(rest %)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vkZKappD2X1kjtSy1qNJeQbla11DBQMGwViM3sUBBV0FVoyi1uERBVVNT878mF5dGQVFmXklOnoJGmkK0oYKRgrGCCRibgqFJrKYmuhpjoLi5giUQmwLZhkAV/wE)

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), <s>66</s> <s>49</s> 55 bytes

**Code**

```
1 >r ( n:- abs dup 1 > if rdrop 0 >r then ) a:y drop r>
```

**SED** (Stack Effect Diagram) is: `a -- f`

**Explanation**

This code leaves `1` on TOS if array is *insignificant*, otherwise it leaves `0`. Here the ungolfed version:

```
1 >r                                           \ suppose array is insignificant
( n:- n:abs dup 1 n:> if rdrop 0 >r then ) a:y \ compute corresponding (absolute) differences and check if difference is > 1
drop r>                                        \ clean stack and put result on TOS
```

We could immediately exit from loop with `break` when array is *significant*, but in this case we waste 6 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## **Python 3, 49 bytes**

```
lambda l:all(abs(j-i)<=1 for i,j in zip(l,l[1:]))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for arrays like `[1, 1, 3]`.

Comment: Great catch on that edge case!! Updated with another answer. @Dennis

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://www.github.com/isaac1g/pyth), <s>15</s> 12 bytes

Works pretty simply. `T` or 10 as a boolean is `True`

```
V.+Q=&T<N2)T
```

Explanation:

```
V.+Q        In the difference map of the input...
    =&T<N2) T = T && the current item is less than 2, and close the loop
T           Print J
```

[Test Suite](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=V.%2BQ%3D%26T%3CN2%29T&input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C4%2C3%2C21%2C1%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C4%2C3%2C2%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C4%2C3%2C21%2C1%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

**Scheme - 89 bytes**

```
(define (f n) (if (not (empty? n)) (and (<= (abs (- (cadr n) (car n))) 1) (f (cdr n))) 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Casio-Basic, 28 bytes

```
judge(max(abs(⊿list(n)))<2
```

It's nice that the fx-CP400 has a built-in for cumulative differences. Not so nice that you need to use `judge` to force it to check whether the resulting value is less than 2.

27 bytes for the function (`⊿` is two bytes), +1 to enter `n` in the argument list.

Comment: If Jelly uses Unicode characters and just count 1 byte, why wouldn't `⊿` also count just 1 byte?

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ If by "Unicode" you mean UTF-8, [most Jelly programs don't use UTF-8](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page).

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ Jelly uses its own code page, as linked in the comment above, which means that every single character used in the language counts as one byte, even if it's two in Unicode. On the Casio ClassPad, that character has a character code above 256, which makes it a two-byte character.

Comment: @Jordan Yes, you are right, I read something more about Jelly and get it!

Comment: It should be measured by how many bytes it takes on the calculator. Which if it's tokenized, could be much less than 26 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), Filename: 40 bytes + Content: 0 bytes = 40 bytes.

- Filename (escaped): `._\001.-.c._.t.w\001.-._.c.m.-\001.x.d.a.t.c.aY.o`
- Content: empty

### Usage

Input is from STDIN; output from STDOUT.
First positive integer N for input represents number of items in list.
Then integers c1, c2, ..., cN represents each item of the list.
Each input has to be separated by one or more s.

An output of `Y` represents truthy, and no output falsey.

#### Input example

List `[1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 4]` is:

```
10
1 2 3 4 3 4 5 5 5 4
```

### With comments

```
XX.z
.a._\001.-.cXX.z # push N; decrement it
.a._.tXX.z # push c1; heap<-c1
.a.w\001.-XX.z # while N!=0; do N--
  .a._.c.m.-\001.xXX.z # push ci; if abs(ci-heap); then
    .a.dXX.z # exit
  .a.aXX.z # fi
  .a.tXX.z # heap=ci
.a.c.aXX.z # done
.aY.oXX.z # putchar o
.a
```

### Link

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRj9V9rI9vf@FcMswgzkE7BVhtFVtLvsKnXV7VOBetIklGhIgASFAv3X@@5MEgTbc97bPaclM/feud9z7x0dKxp8/wVV@2@rpvPZMk3XtJx@dd/e2zX7ZtU27b77ru9W9/atSnW//@YXNJq5Q0@raEMv0EZh5M28aPgmcmOkulM2HVrRIzKMSoW5s1E4idFZ8/7o7Iw3GYnnIxd9cWM7DPqFgtzZ4XBoBQ490B33SQ@mvo8qBwWzUEgPXxxd/85xnqR0SB1lDCSK5hfiU66vkoW6wpnYv9utm/ur6xNeMYxqBrz4cNW6Obu9b364vDxtXnOTdZAaIJxfHB9d/X7/8fTyqvWhXQc2qFcoLJC0KkTSSiY25WO2Wp@5@9kRdzj1rdhF0UAcCEcxrJ7DiRONfC9mlu9ZEVK/oGJ@YZZx/le8KvKi@BZZ@@@zs@b5Ca9LEWC0EOiwaOD1YyncQYIwBbj2IET5XyhGHJlCNJGQaOCCD@MwRKHvHBREFLwYmZS5T5aPcA71LT9y8XL5E3K0SS81kDSzZeQ6qBjpM32uswh@vupFKfcr6i2XYLLkBDQ/iAVLwAP@E9/fZxDCkee7hJI@N5htRS5IMDHyAkT6JYr6EA3mRpbNrChyh5/9uQh8CDE/CpD6FE/NZTxBajNChlmp1nbfvtvbR8VONyj1issvE3eEtKX1/IiKx6e/tdoLH4Q4vPaWgXfJaOIFcR8VRxfhh6Dtte7tZnT19LH/3j2dXD7/Z3Yzv/16Zx3F18Nz56Ss5vI7O8XlvxCdNzhudjDKGwj3eBdjcIkfPrsTEiUqELxjYyVvUIpwFzPMwJFFmRoEY@VKwXVMmVC9zyOOMeuHE8Ig430vcFH/wGB04fVJBoga3KCSDoCR8GSzUOhz7tDFKaFMikTNTtRjKxeijgSVxD4PRCSS9RnpUyGOvWacYAQjGUyDrVZrMT8KkBKSI2ckogAQFKv@NLBjLwzQGbGl7nYO9KVRbNmPHb9c7nF7gwiOCBqfLhJ3YT91gQ@m@6pKUzDCKOWgmr1EDXDCalWUYVCfUAi5IzMPZ/mQmJwaeADWBWWud55n8689XdUtXZgfNIxUMtYsdFxDWkKAl9i2IJ0hsfE6syUdBJokXKyefojRr6BZUAZ2dTBSsAylQbqjFwq5gKaOTCB0MeWBarJEs@BguhlbGYBUlUQJ9KyHSLN@qstrWxLlsJXqAxQydsE/YJnFHBKUpddnJ@p2ReHL7idekg5K3IxUP0YVUYaA0zKLgsUN8YEMzUPMYDUAQDEqgctGYWBHT5O4p5eI1TBpWe@U4dqpyb5CIT7uLGYrfaQvgA2LoDqsoobJ4H@KGsBqAIbHeimXs9hqEfGc3um7aTSYJZzi3ff0su4D1/Z7FcQQC2IPCtjgqE4YRKAAAAcCqA91FdAmrDJd2MqEG/rKzOqWmcXFRccrGz2eN9iIi3VZ5ORqlPsG2ZtZ4euCTK30@Ai9v0LR9HMUT0jeUKqUXXRU1evxGxDWIG2eVIORYinvrygtFEDVBdATnMcAQVan3VMSXpQ5ru9Cr0k4sFW7UQX6SMhKWa4XqR5Rygt1PqFeGTjerHm9qNE@qEA7EU4AF0Cn0Dv5nR4ksBBdgh@wD@Iz42LP5jyBiKSeNeZ0VuZzlcz5DMoDz@7vA6@whwaQMTpKPGB1HuDys02nQI4RvVvWD2fleR3CczhT4ZuDbwm@O/DdmdehB/1g9mn7ZJFIMUCKx5IqAWgpAjI4a2BwHbRSXtfXRVvC9U8@Arfoumhuwi8l/YIUKNO/wB7p8PkMfUymrHcPSdt3J/GwB67UC1DhdBaz7O4BKLnMgKALibEEcCWXjliKbiRaa3/dt2X3LIrrRgxaXC6TvQOsJ248nQSiQyRSyoKB5TiZVFXso89xts@JPYwf2b6bFwDHe8oAO5IgzBhEulbS/3P9nuACFCvwyivN1m0zqaBXnUcOeQ53MetXg6RfFaGbx1mRKAp/L9dH16XdJcd08VguM2DT4/AjckZE7Rg4HjcElB2XyxQWynFKAItXzIXqIIDKfuwgqEeUwS2M7Ik3inmqqOhSrut8wxo0mgmMjXK72YwuyAkV9ih/EtrjJ1InUG27ESXuz/251cb@WCMQIA7MDdSfLyhpzQvmegsjhMoSscbfkEu6uORAJjVR1TT06HKDaEqaafkmqtmARt9sVHbf0sNmXbS@Ndlvghd4YBp80zVdsJ0GbBqIIeGFabpad8PDvFFXN235WwiDU80N2BE5z/rHUR0r55tdIwHnXtrH@tSIZONGDpxKp@QGfjfwYdLyf44MSEsZKyeK/0KzGHMgghnJd4Mv8YCMqcyiFvSHVoP7rAU5NCXkhKc1dqy0FJPSb7hjqPs9fHhSru3Va7tiQFmL8UCHC/Lbtux7cq40lTvlli7OOdbu66gdxqJIuV/cCWZNDvTsDsTKASUZzGrvksDs7tHPE9d6FEWx@Q1/qnWqu708pos7XqupzfRwQiIaM9lLzpk1aEZNzquiASZE8NaJvWDqspXwf0LdbNT2BOHB7jtKJVjq8CI9EUBv@S0iTRWImQgouyB3pdtNG@0N51@Q620HRBvIm61L8ARheVA@Ull1wfUG3PgHLtMagvAAvvgoLrDS6jH5EWOeWDwk@wdV7fGPmwGYbIgSiwm8uMLAnxcKoJMYhY4I1iZ1BEsszBCXQF5sWhIZsxXM55fLBuygFAFFDlhs6D8jfynjRCLcZ5pSm@wvmVpJgqXAvxrjjYPzf3DwYPPg17VSJDma6ZWqvyaMNzwxEJVy2/PDBP0ohvABhEyQbOIdEZlNkrRVCjr2CIVlK2KyTLVE7S1DPSLi6pTIg/xNKiKlSdi4JBHxfBElG5GQ9IdMHtCz/Or2itbUWpPADQPBQKIKsoZxqLbqra3Iyda1xbH0iqPoZeO0GvyR5gqRbgeVffnlabbk6@jOnYS5db6MD/zDse7XfX1M6aZU6If/J8@dn/LcAZ47kqdo7t/ft4/OT3lRu@8ahqmpmq3da7H2nO7uYT/UVLmbaY5mAc7WrFstLL5pfmhfn7avebH4Pe13OC@54WX6eEb9N2tMSv2Cs9@8PvVsI9WG@vyTQz@g1v7oQwzWL@aNE//uOdy@ROK1BsNxcRmJP8Goj8gMJoqZzWSfZF0uoS7RSl2ah9Gra4phhK4wvDxE4@ZyZFJtJP9GNBX3PhyK@QSAkx@AL2o6NaS2a1sEYjCJAB@ikecobuwNXWVkj6bKU/SVOVbs0k0za//bzNjyfKQGtUpmDhhBtO5ir7sSxnRNvfjyGFIrZu1dba/6trYHzwZ4noBX5PCazKtW8tj6534WT6zET@KDxQstG4lwRjDm3aL4fri8gvzKRjpRDTyYvzwxSjB4ulC7A2@A9R8rut2dECseXEEYLuVclc7WY4S7AYQHziatP@n7Sf@HF8Tlzq7BuZlaFiGc5RMaw6H09CpF2528kY7xP4qAN300QGr0ffdNdQ9V38l/e8j8Lw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 28 bytes

```factor
[ [ - [-1,1]? ] monotonic? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU9BTsMwELz3FcOdVN4khgYkOCIuXBCnqAfLctoIYgd7c0BV3x6Mo0pJisa7Ws@MR@tGaXZ@/Hh/fXt5wMG7oW/tAZ3iY2rbZrCaW2cDgvkejNUmoPeG@af3rWU8bk6bEwg5CpSpZEKJM26QPYH9YGYOiTvcY4cq1tJRLLDWyoRJm@b/82csIi3To3xNUyRl3KOKJeNMF0OjvsIUR4uVqVo75p/5C7kKyKOBBGiXuhBXDoFcoLichXoea9TIUGd0S/tn7NE569jZVsfL2KkegZX@3I6/)

`monotonic?` is a combinator that tests if a quotation returns true for every pair of adjacent elements in a sequence.

- `-` Subtract.
- `[-1,1]?` Is it between -1 and 1 inclusive? (This is just the name of a word, like most everything in Factor.)

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 36 bytes

```arturo
$[a][n:a\0every? a'x[2>abs n-x n:x]]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?Ru6hXu)

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
┘ε≡}◄ï╖Z
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=d9eef07d118bb75a&i=%5B1,+2,+3,+4,+3,+4,+5,+5,+5,+4%5D%0A%5B1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6,+7,+8,+9,+8%5D%0A%5B3,+3,+3,+3,+3,+3,+3%5D%0A%5B3,+4,+4,+4,+3,+3,+3,+4,+4,+4%5D%0A%5B1,+2,+3,+4%5D+%0A%5B5,+4,+3,+2%5D%0A%5B1,+3,+5,+7,+9,+7,+5,+3,+1%5D%0A%5B1,+1,+1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6,+19%5D%0A%5B3,+4,+5,+6,+7,+8,+7,+5%5D%0A%5B1,+2,+4,+10,+18,+10,+100%5D%0A%5B10,+20,+30,+30,+30%5D&m=2)

Link includes all test cases.

Unpacked:

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 10 bytes

```
:-{|a2<m:*
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%3A-%7B%7Ca2%3Cm%3A*&i=%5B1,+2,+3,+4,+3,+4,+5,+5,+5,+4%5D%0A%5B1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6,+7,+8,+9,+8%5D%0A%5B3,+3,+3,+3,+3,+3,+3%5D%0A%5B3,+4,+4,+4,+3,+3,+3,+4,+4,+4%5D%0A%5B1,+2,+3,+4%5D+%0A%5B5,+4,+3,+2%5D%0A%5B1,+3,+5,+7,+9,+7,+5,+3,+1%5D%0A%5B1,+1,+1,+2,+3,+4,+5,+6,+19%5D%0A%5B3,+4,+5,+6,+7,+8,+7,+5%5D%0A%5B1,+2,+4,+10,+18,+10,+100%5D%0A%5B10,+20,+30,+30,+30%5D&m=2)

```
:-          # pairwise differences/deltas
  {     m   # mapped by
   |a       # absolute value of n
     2<     # is less than 2
         :* # product of array (essentially all(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Kamilalisp](https://github.com/kspalaiologos/kamilalisp), 31 bytes (APL385 SBCS)

```
$(∧?∘⌹‡⍡ 2 $(> 2)∘abs∘$(⌿⊙← -))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70qOzE3MycxJ7O4YMEyjZTUNIW0paUlaboWN41VNB51LLd_1DHjUc_ORw0LH_UuVDBSUNGwUzDSBAomJhUDSaCanv2PumY-apugoKupCdWqqcnFpZGZb1VelFmSmpOnEJOmoK5hCNRtrGACxqZgaALTsGABhAYA)